# Is there a version of König's theorem for tripartite 3-graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraph, packing-and-covering, matching-theory

I would like to know if there exists a version of König's theorem for tripartite $3$-graphs.

In other words, let $G = (V,T)$ be a tripartite $3$-graph.  That is, $V$ is a set of vertices (with $V$ equal to the union of three disjoint subsets $A,B,C$) and $T$ is a set of hyperedges $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, with $v_1 \in A, v_2 \in B, v_3 \in C$. A *matching* is a collection of hyperedges such that no two of them share a vertex.  A *cover* is a set of vertices that meets every hyperedge.

> Is there a relationship between the size of a maximum matching and the size of a minimum cover in $G$.

Any suggestions or references?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may also be interested in this result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_in_hypergraphs#K%C5%91nig's_property which says that every balanced hypergraph has the Konig property (so its maximum matching size equals its minimum cover size). I am not sure if every tripartite hypergraph is balanced.

Answer (score 19):

This is a special case of [Ryser's Conjecture](http://garden.irmacs.sfu.ca/?q=op/rysers_conjecture), which states that in 
an $r$-partite, $r$-uniform hypergraph (with $r>1$)

> $\tau \leq (r-1) \nu$,

where $\tau$ is the size of a minimum cover and $\nu$ is the size of a maximum matching. Note that the case $r=2$ is simply König's theorem.

You are interested in the case $r=3$, which was settled by Aharoni.  The reference is

*Ryser's conjecture for tripartite 3-graphs.*  Combinatorica 21 (2001), no. 1, 1--4,

and you can find a copy of the paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220442360_Ryser's_Conjecture_for_Tripartite_3-Graphs).