# Non-diagonalizable complex symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, tag-removed, matrices, quadratic-forms

This is a question in elementary linear algebra, though I hope it's not so trivial to be closed.

Real symmetric matrices, complex hermitian matrices, unitary matrices, and complex matrices with distinct eigenvalues are diagonalizable, i.e. conjugate to a diagonal matrix.

> I'd just like to see an example of a complex symmetric $n\times n$ matrix that is not diagonalizable.

Comment: It's nontrivial but surely falls under "homework" rubric

Comment: It's homework level difficulty but, if you look at this user's past history, it probably isn't homework. 

Comment: It appears to be well-known (or in my case, I was told in a seminar) that every complex square matrix is *similar* to a complex symmetric one, but not necessarily unitarily so. (See the comments on page 1 of 
http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2728v2 ) In particular, any non-trivial nilpotent would do.

Comment: @David: I know, for I gave it to him (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23552#23552)! :)

Comment: @Victor: excuse me, but I don't understand how can Gram-Schmidt and isotropic vectors be related to this problem (ok, "exercise" ;) ), as I'm looking for diagonalizing a (symmetric) matrix $A$ as an operator ($BAB^{-1}$), not as a quadratic form ($B^tAB$). A priori, $A$ could be non-orthogonally diagonalizable. Right?

Comment: @YC: thanks for the reference. I didn't know that every operator was "symmetrizable" (in that sense). 

Comment: @Unknown: What do you call the rows (and columns) of David's matrix below if not isotropic? That's where the usual proof of diagonalizability over R breaks down, and sure enough, you get a non-diagonalizable matrix. 

Answer (score 40, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

How did I find this? Non-diagonalizable means that there is some Jordan block of size greater than $1$. I decided to hunt for something with Jordan form $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$. So I want trace and determinant to be zero, but the matrix not to be zero. The diagonal entries made sure the trace vanished, and then the off diagonal entries were forced.

Comment: @David In what sense is the above matrix symmetric?  (Definitely not in the sense of it being being equal to its transpose). Further one knows that $3\times 3$ symmetric traceless real matrices support an irreducible representation of $SO(3)$. Is there any analogous statement known for complex symmetric matrices or for the double cover $SU(2)$ or $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ ? 

Comment: In the sense that it is equal to its transpose. There are two off diagonal entries, and they are equal.

Comment: @David. Sorry for the first question. It was stupid of me. So any comments about the representation theory aspect of complex symmetric matrices as in comparison to real case which I was mentioning? 

Comment: How about this quiz - generalizing autonne takagi factorization: https://mathoverflow.net/q/302741/27004

Comment: @DavidESpeyer  Why do we look for trace and determinant to be 0?

Comment: @rannoudanames the question requires a matrix with two equal eigenvalues, David chose to set them both to zero.