# Proofs of the uncountability of the reals

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, big-list

Recently, I learnt in my analysis class the proof of the uncountability of the reals via the [Nested Interval Theorem](http://personal.bgsu.edu/%7Ecarother/cantor/Nested.html) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180402194030/http://personal.bgsu.edu/%7Ecarother/cantor/Nested.html)). At first, I was excited to see a variant proof (as it did not use the diagonal argument explicitly). However, as time passed, I began to see that the proof was just the old one veiled under new terminology. So, till now I believe that any proof of the uncountability of the reals must use Cantor's diagonal argument.

Is my belief justified?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not too hard to see that the reals have the same cardinality as the power set of the naturals.  So we are reduced to showing that a set cannot have the same cardinality as its power set.  This is shown using the same argument as the Russell Paradox (i.e., assume a bijection $\phi \colon \mathcal{P}(X) \to X$ exists, and take the set $T$ of all $x \in X$ such that $x \not\in \phi^{-1}(x)$. Then ask whether $\phi(T) \in T$.)  I don't think this is the same as the diagonal argument, although I can imagine that someone sufficiently determined might be able to argue otherwise.

Comment: No. Cantor's first proof of uncountability actually does not use the diagonal argument. Instead, he first proves the countability of algebraic numbers and then states uncountability as a corollary. See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_uncountability_proof


Comment: @Charles: Yanofsky, "A Universal Approach to Self-Referential Paradoxes, Incompleteness and Fixed Points" (http://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/0903/0903-004.ps).

Comment: Why the votes to close?  I think that this is an interesting question.  For what it's worth I cast a vote to *keep open* which should be taken into account by the next person wishing to vote to close.  If you wish to do so, then please let's take this to meta, where I have started this thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/789/proofs-of-the-uncountability-of-the-reals/

Comment: @Francesco: no, the uncountability isn’t a corollary of the countability of the algebraics!  Cantor’s original uncountability argument is what the OP refers to as the Nested Interval Theorem.  The corollary Cantor then draws from this, together with countability of the algebraics, is the existence of transcendentals (lots of ’em) within any interval.

Comment: This question seems related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23953/earliest-diagonal-proof-of-the-uncountability-of-the-reals

Comment: The nested interval method and the diagonal method are fundamentally the same method, as is the Russell paradox method. These are all the diagonal method. 

Comment: @Charles: I don’t want to seem particularly determined, but isn’t $\{x\ |\ \varphi^{-1}(x) \notin x\}$ exactly the diagonal argument?  It’s always referred to as such by logicians (see e.g. http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/15/tr15abs.html or most Set Theory texts), and given as an example of such by Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#General_sets.

Comment: @Peter. You are right, thank you. At first glance, it seemed to me quite a different proof. But reading it more carefully, I'm now convinced that the core of the argument is again the diagonal method...

Comment: I also cast a vote _against_ closing.  The question is: "Is there a different proof of this theorem?" which, to me, sounds very interesting and a natural question that a mathematically mature but non-expert-in-set-theory person might ask.  I've asked several questions that have exposed my lamentable ignorance of the subtleties of mathematical foundations and, so far, all have received very interesting and informative answers.  This one feels as though it is in the same vein as those.

Comment: @J.F.O'Farrill and Andrew. Yes!Yes!Yes! You said it.

Comment: The second paragraph pp.364 of the paper linked above by Martin gives me a new light with respect to paradoxes: "...there really are no paradoxes. There are limitations."

Comment: This seems like a real nice question, only I'd say it fits better on http://math.stackexchage.com and not here.

Comment: I voted to close because it seems to me that the above debate shows precisely what's wrong with the question: whether or not an argument "is a diagonal argument" seems to be open to interpretation.

Comment: I also vote against closing. It's an interesting question. A nice proof based on the property that each bounded subset of the reals has a surpremum can be found in <a href="http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0901/0901.0446v1.pdf">this article.</a> 

Comment: I correct the link just ahead: http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0446

Comment: @Kevin-Buzzard, I disagree with your contention that: *whether or not an argument "is a diagonal argument" seems to be open to interpretation.*  It is not simply a matter of interpretation if the underlying argument is diagonalization; it's a matter of the structure of the proof.  I would like to cast a "virtual vote" to reopn this question, and I believe that this question had enough merit and substance to it that it ought not to have been closed in the first place.  Also, a virtual thumbs to Elohemabab Solomon up for asking this question, and a smiley face too :) ...

Comment: Kevin, I think that there is much less disagreement about whether an argument is a diagonalization than your comment suggests. Most logicians view all the various forms of diagonalization that have been mentioned as fundamentally similar. Meanwhile, my view is that if there were a fundamentally different method of proving Cantor's theorem, this would be important news.  So I voted to re-open. 

Comment: Ralph - my understanding of the "verbally vote to keep open" system is that only people who already have the ability to vote to close or reopen may do so (though of course everyone is welcome to voice their approval or disapproval of a question in the comments). Just wanted to point out that it may confuse people who wanted to vote to close but saw your comment and decided not to (it doesn't appear to have; no one has posted that they have canceled your vote to keep open).

Comment: I voted to re-open. It looks to me that the question of whether Cantor's theorem essentially needs diagonalization is both subtle and interesting. I believe it is possible to avoid a diagonal argument, and I am including a proof which hopefully does not hide one somewhere. (Please let me know if you spot a mistake.)

Comment: In the thread on common false beliefs in mathematics, wasn't one of those false beliefs the proposition that the diagonal argument was how Cantor first proved uncountability?  If not, maybe it should have been.  [Cantor's first uncountability proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_first_uncountability_proof) was published some time before he published the diagonal argument.

Comment: @Joel: I still do not buy it. You are a logician, right? Are you claiming that this is a formal mathematical question? If so, then go ahead and formalise the notion of "this proof uses a diagonalization". If you don't think this can be done, then where is the question? I don't really see one. I think that if you look at the answers given thus far, they are perhaps interesting, but none of them remotely deals with this point, so they are at the end of the day "opinion", which is exactly what I am voting against.

Comment: @Kevin, I buy what you are demanding but I still value the opinions. In retrospect, I would not have ever imagined such answers and suggestions were I not to ask.Thanks for your involvement.

Comment: Kevin, my criterion for keeping MO questions open has almost entirely to do with the level of mathematical sophistication, rather than degree of formalization, and questions of the form "Can we prove fundamental theorem X with (or without) method Y" are on topic. Although as you and Timothy Chow point out, ruling out a method seems difficult, providing a postive instance does not. In particular, if there is a proof of Cantor's theorem that differs fundamentally from those I know, I am keen to learn about it. Bill's answer comes close, but is at bottom still a diagonalization.

Comment: The reals are complete, that seems to be a rather pertinent fact.  Perhaps you can use some manner of argument along those lines, though I too am no logician, I don't know if something about completeness requires diagonalization under some guise or other.

Comment: One could also ask whether uncountability of reals depends on the Axiom of Choice. Since the diagonalization argument seems to depend on the Axiom of Choice, a proof that doesn't couldn't possibly be a veiled version of Cantor's argument.

Comment: The diagonalization argument doesn't use the axiom of choice.  It uses the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein Theorem (to show that $\mathbb{R} \simeq \mathcal{P}\mathbb{N}$), which needs only Excluded Middle (although it's simpler if you use the Well-Ordering Theorem, as Cantor did).  That $\mathbb{N} \not\simeq \mathcal{P}\mathbb{N}$ is fully constructive (although it's simpler if you use Excluded Middle, as Cantor did).

Comment: You can find such proofs (ones that use only the set-theoretic/logical axioms that are needed) at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein+theorem and http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cantor%27s+theorem

Comment: Cantor's diagonal argument in base $2$ is very similar to Russel's paradox.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Mathematics isn't yet ready to prove results of the form, "Every proof of Theorem T *must use* Argument A."  Think closely about how you might try to prove something like that.  You would need to set up some *plausible system for mathematics* in which Cantor's diagonal argument is blocked and *the reals are countable*.  Nobody has any idea how to do that.

The best you can hope for is to look at each proof on a case-by-case basis and decide, subjectively, whether it is "essentially the diagonal argument in disguise."  If you're lucky, you'll run into one that your intuition tells you is a fundamentally different proof, and that will settle the question to your satisfaction.  But if that doesn't happen, then the most you'll be able to say is that every *known* proof seems *to you* to be the same.  As explained above, you won't be able to conclude definitively that every possible argument *must* use diagonalization.

**ADDENDUM** (August 2020). Normann and Sanders have a [very interesting paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.07560) that sheds new light on the uncountability of $\mathbb R$.  In particular they study two specific formulations of the uncountability of $\mathbb R$:

$\mathsf{NIN}$: For any $Y:[0,1] \to \mathbb{N}$, there exist $x,y \in [0,1]$ such that $x\ne_{\mathbb{R}} y$ and $Y(x) =_{\mathbb{N}} Y(y)$.

$\mathsf{NBI}$: For any $Y[0,1] \to \mathbb{N}$, either there exist $x,y \in [0,1]$ such that $x\ne_{\mathbb{R}} y$ and $Y(x) =_{\mathbb{N}} Y(y)$, or there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(\forall x\in [0,1])(Y(x) \ne N)$.

One of their results is that a system called ${\mathsf Z}_2^\omega$ does not prove $\mathsf{NIN}$.  Their model of $\neg\mathsf{NIN}$ can therefore be interpreted as a situation where the reals are countable! Nevertheless we are still far from showing that Cantor's diagonal argument is needed to prove that the reals are uncountable.  A further caveat is that Normann and Sanders argue that the unprovability of $\mathsf{NIN}$ in ${\mathsf Z}_2^\omega$—which might at first sight suggest that $\mathsf{NIN}$ is a strong axiom—is an artificial result, and that the proper framework for studying $\mathsf{NIN}$ and $\mathsf{NBI}$ is what they call a “non-normal scale,” in which $\mathsf{NIN}$ and $\mathsf{NBI}$ are very weak.  In particular their paper gives lots of examples of statements that imply $\mathsf{NIN}$ and $\mathsf{NBI}$. I suspect, though, that you'll probably feel that the proofs of those other statements smuggle in Cantor's diagonal argument one way or another.

**ADDENDUM** (December 2022).
I just listened to an [amazing talk by Andrej Bauer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CBFUojXoq4), reporting on joint work with James Hanson.
If you start listening around [14:53](https://youtu.be/4CBFUojXoq4?t=893), you'll see how, in the context of intuitionistic logic, one can formulate precisely the question of whether there is a proof of the uncountability of the reals that doesn't use diagonalization.  Bauer and Hanson don't answer this question, but they construct something they call a "parameterized realizability topos" in which *the Dedekind reals are countable*.  In particular, this shows that higher-order intuitionistic logic (in which one cannot formulate the usual diagonalization argument) cannot show the reals are uncountable.  Now, you could still justifiably claim that this whole line of research does not really address the original question, which I presume tacitly assumes classical logic; nevertheless, this still comes closer than anything else I've seen.

Comment: Oh...Thank you. I did not think the question will go this far. So, the question is pretty like the statement in Cosmology: "The observable universe is finite but nobody yet knows whether it is infinite or not, let alone boundedness."

Comment: Well, there is Quine's New Foundations in set theory, in which the diagonal argument is blocked from disproving the existence of a set of all sets, because of the inability to express the predicate $x \not \in x$.  But I gather that NF does not block the diagonal argument from demonstrating the uncountability of the reals, so this isn't quite an answer to the problem at hand...

Comment: Thank you. Now, I know that it is possible to block diagonalization  in some setting. 

Comment: Reverse mathematics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) is almost exactly about studying which axioms and arguments are necessary for certain theorems. If you want to know whether axiom X is necessary for a theorem Y, you can try to see if there's a model of Y in which X doesn't hold. It's not as easy to see whether a certain argument is necessary, but often you can axiomatize what it means to be able to do a certain argument, e.g. there are systems which capture what it means to be able to use a compactness argument, or induction, or transfinite recursion, etc. 

Comment: @Amit: Yes, I'm familiar with reverse mathematics.  But let me repeat what I said above: Think closely!  How would you axiomatize what it means to be able to diagonalize?  What candidate do you have in mind for a model in which *the reals are countable*?  I stand by what I said; nobody has a clue.

Comment: 1. Are you saying reverse math never proves results of the form "Argument A is necessary for Theorem T" (in some reasonable sense of the word "necessary")? 2. You presume that diagonalization is necessary for Cantor's theorem - someone who believes not wouldn't need a model where the reals are countable. 3. Why is it that "being able to diagonalize" can't be axiomatized?  A huge variety of arguments get referred to as compactness arguments, so naively one would think you couldn't axiomatize "being able to do a compactness argument", but doesn't Weak Konig's Lemma sort of do just that?

Comment: Actually following Terry's comment, "being able to diagonalize" might be axiomatized a scheme for Comprehension or Separation involving non-stratifiable formulas.

Comment: @Amit: 1. No. 2. No, I'm not presuming that "diagonalization is necessary for Cantor's theorem"; that's what Solomon was conjecturing, and I'm just saying we're not in a position to prove such a thing. 3. Maybe it's possible, but I don't think anyone has any idea how to do it. I don't think your proposal about non-stratifiable formulas will work, but if you can do it, more power to you.  Here's another context where we'd love to axiomatize diagonalization: in computational complexity, folklore says that "diagonalization relativizes."  There's still no good axiomatization of this "fact."

Comment: @TimothyChow: I agree with both you and Amit. Following on Amit's comments, I'd like to draw your attention to the seeming conflict between your answer to his question 1, and the first sentence of your posted answer. I think a fairer answer, which I hope you'd agree with, might be to say that Reverse Math would be the right domain in which to *try* to prove that diagonalization is necessary for uncountability of the reals, but the difficulty is that no one has any idea how to formalize the notion of "diagonalization" within Reverse Math.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow : I don't really see what is gained by using the term "reverse math" here.  It comes down to what I said at first: one needs to construct a plausible system for mathematics in which the reals are countable.  I think that this is a clearer and more accurate way to describe the obstacle than to talk about "how to formalize the notion of diagonalization within reverse math."

Comment: @TimothyChow: I agree with you in terms of clarity of the underlying issue. However, the point of mentioning Reverse Math is that it is an active area of mathematical research that deals precisely with questions of the form "Is A necessary to prove B?", but it is an area of math that many mathematicians are not aware even exists (and they cannot even conceive how one *might* prove such a statement). So, in that sense, I suppose mentioning this area of math is more for the benefit of advertising than anything else.

Comment: @TimothyChow From what I've seen, I agree with you that this sort of mathematics hasn't been studied at nearly the level required to prove such a theorem, but "nobody has any idea", I don't think is a very good way to surmise the situation. In particular, for set theory developed over a certain paraconsistent logic, Cantor's theorem is unprovable. See "What is wrong with Cantor's diagonal argument?" by Ross Brady and Penelope Rush. So, if one developed enough of reverse mathematics in such a context, one could I think meaningfully ask this question.

Comment: @NathanBeDell : thanks for the reference, which is interesting and which I didn't know about. However, I still think that this paper gives us *no idea* how to answer the original question, which is a question about classical logic. One could formulate an *analogous* question in the context of a non-classical logic, and maybe even answer it, but it would still not address the original question of whether every classical proof of the classical theorem must use diagonalization.

Answer (score 68):

Mathematical logicians often joke that the diagonal method is the only proof method that we have in logic. This method is the principal idea behind a huge number of fundamental results, among them:

- The uncountability of the reals.
- More generally, the fact that the power set $P(X)$ of a set is strictly larger in cardinality.
- The Russell paradox.
- The undecidability of the halting problem.
- The Recursion theorem.
- More generally, huge parts of computability theory are based on diagonalization, such as uses of the priority method.
- The fixed-point lemma and its use in proving the Incompleteness theorem.
- The strictness of the arithmetic hierarchy, the projective hierarchy, etc.
- Etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you. All this evidence is not a joke for me. By now I believe the founding of diagonal argumentation is tantamount to the the founding of the group concept. 

Comment: A lot of these can be captured by Lawvere's formalisation of the diagonal argument as a fixed-point theorem: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/15/tr15abs.html

Comment: David, I agree, but another perspective is simply that the fixed-point theorem is another instance of diagonalization. That is, these arguments are already unified as diagonalizations.

Comment: Joel - I agree that calling them diagonalisation arguments or fixed point theorems is just a point of linguistics (actually the diagonal argument is the contrapositive of the fixed point version), it's just that Lawvere's version, to me at least, looks more like a single theorem than a collection of results that rely on an particular line of reasoning. This, I hope, helps the OP or those answering the question in isolating what a diagonal argument "is", and avoid it if possible.

Comment: In a sense, Gödel incompleteness is also proved using this method

Comment: Yes, I had mentioned that on the list.

Comment: The existence of forcing extensions is also an application of  diagonalization.

Comment: @PéterKomjáth:  Interesting.  How so?

Comment: Thomas, I presume that Péter is referring to the process of constructing a generic filter: one lines up the dense sets and meets them one-by-one, which is a kind of diagonalization.

Comment: Thomas, Joel: Exactly.

Comment: @DavidRoberts there is a nice expository blog post by Andrej Bauer about Lawvere's result [here](http://math.andrej.com/2007/04/08/on-a-proof-of-cantors-theorem/)

Answer (score 40):

What about using Lebesgue outer measure? The interval $[0,1]$ has Lebesgue outer measure 1, while countable sets have Lebesgue outer measure $0$.

For the purposes of the proof, I define the Lebesgue outer measure $\mathcal{L}(E)$ of a set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ as the infimum of the sums $\sum_i (b_i-a_i)$, where $E\subset \bigcup_i (a_i,b_i)$ (e.g. the infimum is over all countable coverings by open intervals).

It is a direct consequence of the definition that any countable set has Lebesgue outer measure 0. This can be even proved in the spirit of Gowers' first suggestion: suppose that $f:\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)\to A$ is a bijection. Then, given $\varepsilon>0$, the family $$\{ ( f(p/q)-\varepsilon/q^3, f(p/q)+\varepsilon/q^3): p/q\in [0,1], \text{g.c.d.}(p,q)=1\}$$
is a cover of $A$ by intervals, such that the sum of the lengths is $O(\varepsilon)$.

To prove that $\mathcal{L}([0,1])=1$, the following is the key claim: Let $\{ (a_i,b_i)\}$ be a finite cover of the interval $[c,d]$ with no proper subcover. Then $\sum_i (b_i-a_i) > d-c$.

The claim is proved by induction in the number of elements of the cover. It is clearly true if the cover has just one interval. Now if $[c,d] \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i)$ with $n>1$, then $[c,d]\backslash (a_1,b_1)$ is either a closed interval $I$ or the union $I\cup I'$ of two disjoint closed intervals. In the first case $\bigcup_{i=2}^n (a_i,b_i)$ is a cover of $I$ and we apply the inductive hypothesis to it. Otherwise, $\{(a_i,b_i)\}_{i=2}^n$ can be split into two disjoint subfamilies, one which covers $I$ and one which covers $I'$. We then apply the inductive hypothesis to these families. (We use the property that the original cover has no proper subcover to make sure the covers of $I$ and $I'$ are disjoint.)

Now the claim and compactness of $[0,1]$ (ie. Heine-Borel) yield that $\mathcal{L}([0,1])\ge 1$.

Hence, $[0,1]$ is uncountable and so is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if you could prove that that family you define doesn't cover the whole of [0,1] without using something very like the nested-intervals version of the diagonal argument. (That is, I'd like to know more about your proof that [0,1] has outer measure 1.)

Comment: I edited my post with a sketch of a proof that $[0,1]$ has outer measure $1$, modulo compactness of closed intervals. I do not see that I'm using a diagonal/nested intervals argument, but I could be totally wrong. The usual proof of Heine-Borel also doesn't appear to me to use a diagonal argument (see e.g. http://www.math.utah.edu/~bobby/3210/heine-borel.pdf). At no point in the proof there is an enumeration of an infinite set. 

Comment: Maybe you've convinced me. One can take the family you describe and define x to be the supremum over all reals x such that [0,x] can be covered by finitely many of its members. Such an x can't be covered itself (since the sets are open). This is just the proof of Heine-Borel in this special case. Also, your lemma gives us that x can't be 1. So one ends up using the least upper bound axiom instead of the nested-intervals property, which is perhaps enough to qualify the argument as genuinely different.

Comment: this proof appears in hardy's pure mathematics, about 100 years ago.

Comment: I am sorry I have the book in hard, but can't find where the proof is. Could you tell me where that is?

Answer (score 36):

Alternatively,

Prove that the reals are connected.

Prove that every countable dense subset $X$ of the reals must be order isomorphic to the rationals.

Prove that the rationals are not connected.

Comment: @Bill : Doesn't the non-connectedness of ${\mathbb Q}$ rely on the uncountability of ${\mathbb R}$? How do you argue about it directly?

Comment: Actually, I thought this held up and looked like an interesting possibility. You just need the existence of an irrational, don't you? 

Comment: The rationals are clearly not connected. Partition then into the open sets of rationals less than $\sqrt{2}$ and the rationals greater than $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: All you need to do is prove that between two rationals is an irrational. A variant of the well known proof that sqrt(2) is irrational should do the trick here. Just exploit the sparsity of squares among "large" integers.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This looks like an interesting method.

Comment: +1. I voted this up, but it doesn't satisfy Gowers criterion (1), since the proof of Cantor's theorem that every countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is order isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ involves enumerating $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I did not understand what point Tim was trying to make in (1) since you can write down an explicit ordering of the rationals.  It does address Tim's number (2).

Comment: If $a\lt b$ are rational then $a+(b-a)/\sqrt2$ is an irrational between them. 

Comment: Bill, the point is that to get the final contradiction, if
$f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the order isomorphism, then
the resulting disconnection of $\mathbb{R}$ is the cut
determined by $f[\{q\mid q\lt\sqrt{2}\}]$, say, which has
least upper bound $z$, but no real works, since the $n$-th
real in the enumeration was placed into the range of $f$ at
stage $n$. So this is diagonalization.

Answer (score 33):

I thought about this question a while ago, while teaching a topics course. Since one can easily check that $${}|{\mathbb R}|=|{\mathcal P}({\mathbb N})|$$ by a direct construction that does not involve diagonalization, the question can be restated as:

> Is there a proof of Cantor's theorem that ${}|X|<|{\mathcal P}(X)|$ that is not a diagonal argument?

I suspect the following works. Even if it doesn't, I believe there may be some interest in this presentation (Please let me know if you spot diagonalization somewhere).

A remark of François Dorais helped me (re)locate the argument in print. It is presented in A. Kanamori-D. Pincus. "Does GCH imply AC locally?", in **Paul Erdős and his mathematics, II (Budapest, 1999)**, 413-426, Bolyai Soc. Math. Stud., 11, János Bolyai Math. Soc., Budapest, 2002. I believe it actually dates back to Zermelo's 1904 well-ordering paper. (I now think I learned the argument from  Kanamori-Pincus, since I certainly used the paper in the topics course.)

**a.** There is obviously an injection $g:X\to{\mathcal P}(X)$. It is enough to show there is no surjection. Suppose there is, and call it $f$. Then $f^{-1}:{\mathcal P}^2(X)\to{\mathcal P}(X)$ is 1-1.

(If $h:A\to B$, $h^{-1}:{\mathcal P}(B)\to{\mathcal P}(A)$ is the map that to $C\subseteq B$ assigns $\{a\in A\mid h(a)\in C\}$. Since $f$ is surjective, we have that $f^{-1}$ is injective.)

(Of course, we could simply use an injection $g:{\mathcal P}(X)\to X$ and invoke Schröder-Bernstein at this point, but this route seems shorter.)

**b.** There is no injection $F:{\mathcal P}(Y)\to Y$ for any set $Y$. The reason is that for any $F$ we can (definably from $F$) produce a pair $(A,B)$ with $A\ne B$ and $F(A)=F(B)$. In effect, Zermelo proved that:

> For any $F:{\mathcal P}(Y)\to Y$ there is a unique well-ordering $(W, \lt)$ with $W\subseteq Y$ such that:
>
> 1. $\forall x\in W (F (\{y ∈ W \mid y \lt x\}) = x)$, and
> 2. $F (W )\in W$.

We can then take $A=W$ and $B=\{y\in W\mid y\lt F(W)\}$.

**c.** *Zermelo's theorem* can be proved as follows: Simply notice that $W=\{a_\alpha\mid \alpha\lt \beta\}$ where $$ a_\alpha= F(\{a_\gamma\mid \gamma\lt \alpha\}) $$ and $\beta$ is largest so that this sequence is injective.

That $\beta$ exists is a consequence of *Hartogs theorem* that for any set $A$ there is a least ordinal $\alpha$ does not inject into $A$.

Uniqueness of $W$ is shown by considering the ﬁrst place where two potential candidates for $(W, \lt)$ disagree.

**d.** Hartogs theorem is proved by noticing that if $\alpha$ is an ordinal and injects into $A$, then there is a subset $B$ of $A$ and a binary relation $R$ on $B$ such that $(B,R)$ is order isomorphic to $\alpha$. From this one easily sees that the collection of $\alpha$s that inject into $A$ forms a set, that is in fact an ordinal $\beta$. Then $\beta$ is least that does not inject into $A$.

---

Let me close with a remark, and a question: The proof above is formalizable in ZF, without choice. In fact, Zermelo's theorem is provable without using replacement, although the argument I sketched uses it.

The question is mentioned in Kanamori-Pincus: We showed that if $F:{\mathcal P}(Y)\to Y$ then $F$ is not injective by exhibiting a pair $(A,B)$ with $F(A)=F(B)$. If instead of Zermelo's argument we had used at this point the construction from the diagonal argument, we would have taken $$ A=\{y\in Y\mid \exists Z(y=F(Z)\notin Z)\}, $$ and checked that there must be a $B\ne A$ with $F(A)=F(B)$.

> Can we *define* such $B$ from $F$?

(**Update:** In general, the answer to the question is no. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/47458/6085).)

---

**Update, Sep. 6, 2017:** Let me add a few additional remarks. First, in comments,  Martin Brandenburg asked why one should bother about trying to obtain a "diagonalization-free" proof. That the proof above avoids diagonalization is perhaps simply a curiosity (though one is left with the question of how to define precisely "diagonalization-free"); what matters is that the argument gives a bit more than Cantor's: As I pointed out in a comment, the proof just given shows that 1) The collection of well-orderable subsets of $X$ has strictly larger size than $X$. This is an improvement over Cantor's result in the context of $\mathsf{}$. 2) Given any $f\!:\mathcal P(X)\to X$, we can find $A\subsetneq B$ with $f(A)=f(B)$. This is also a combinatorial strengthening, and it can be pushed further. Stevo Todorcevic in particular obtained several extensions of this idea, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/629315/462) in Math.Stackexchange.

Second, Hartogs's theorem can be used to provide a different (also "diagonalization-free") proof of Cantor's result, and actually establish a generalization in the context of quasi-ordered sets, due to Gleason and Dilworth. For the pretty argument and appropriate references, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2064374/462).

Comment: Although I think this is very interesting, I still wonder why we bother trying to avoid the diagonal argument by using tons of more advanced arguments, which perhaps in the end, when we enfold them into elementary arguments, use some sort of diagonal argument.

Comment: Hehe. As I mentioned, I found this argument while teaching a topics course; meaning: I was lecturing on ideas related to the arguments above, and while preparing notes for the class, it came to me that one would get a diagonalization-free proof of Cantor's theorem by following the indicated path; I looked in the literature, and couldn't find evidence of this being known. I wasn't explicitly looking for it at any point. Anyway, there is technical interest in the matter, precisely because the argument is so ubiquitous, as Joel's answer indicates.

Comment: Now that I see it, I think I had seen this proof in a talk by Aki Kanamori. If I remember correctly, Aki attributed the proof to Tarski. Since this is from a long time ago, my memory may be off...

Comment: @François : Oh, I should email Aki and ask him, then. Thanks!

Comment: @Martin: I think rather than "coming to me", I read the argument in a paper by Kanamori-Pincus. I added a reference.

Comment: @François : I located a paper from Aki and Pincus where the argument is presented. It actually seems to go back to Zermelo. (And I used the paper in the course I gave, so most likely I originally read it there.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg A very late reply, but here is a reason to bother: The argument shows that 1) The collection of well-orderable subsets of $X$ has strictly larger size than $X$. This is an improvement over Cantor's result in the context of $\mathsf{ZF}$. 2) Given any $f:\mathcal P(X)\to X$, we can find $A\subsetneq B$ with $f(A)=f(B)$. This is also a combinatorial strengthening (and it can be pushed further, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/629315/462)).

Comment: This link to the Kanamori-Pincus was linked in another answer: http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/7.pdf ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20200818080439/http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/7.pdf)).

Answer (score 24):

Although I very much take Timothy Chow's point, and don't have a way of constructing anything like a model where Cantor's diagonal argument is blocked (I'm not sure what the diagonal argument is in the abstract, given that there are variants), some sickness in me makes me want to try to answer the question anyway. One small thought that occurs to me is that all proofs depend (or can be very easily transformed so that they depend) on the following ingredients: a bijection between the countable set and the natural numbers, the use of the ordering on the natural numbers to order the countable set, the construction of a sequence that lives in a sequence of nested intervals that avoid the points of the countable set, one at a time.

Here are some questions that are more specific than the one in the OP. They are off the top of my head and therefore not guaranteed to be sensible.

1. Suppose we tried artificially to block the use of the ordering. It might seem impossible, since the *definition* of countability is that there is a bijection to the natural numbers, but we could, for instance, try proving the result for sets that are in bijection with the rationals and insist that at no point does the proof define an enumeration of that set.
2. Or we could start with the stronger hypothesis that X is a set of reals that is order-isomorphic to the rationals. Is it possible to prove that this set does not contain all reals without at the same time proving that it is countable?

I don't know how relevant this is, but I'd also like to mention a fascinating fact that I heard from Harvey Friedman recently that feels as though it's in the same ball park. He told me that there exists a Borel function f defined on sequences of reals such that for every sequence S the value f(S) is not a term of S. That's easy to prove from the diagonal argument. On the other hand, there is no Borel function from countable *subsets* of reals such that f(X) is not an element of X for any countable set X. (I think I remember that that's what he said, but I'm not certain that the result wasn't stronger.) Equivalently, you can't find an f that works for sequences and is also invariant under permutations of the terms in the sequence. This gives us a sort of hint that some kind of enumeration is essential to the proof, but I don't see how to make that hint into a precise thought.

Comment: I'm obliged for your thoughts. 

Comment: That is a really great point about the importance of having an order for countability. I can't say that I see *why* for every Borel function $f$ defined on countable subsets of reals there is a countable set of reals $X$ such that such that $f(X) \in X$ (if that is a fair restatement) but I don't see any reason to doubt that. 

Comment: In case somebody missed it, Aaron posted the above as a question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47185/why-is-there-no-borel-function-mapping-every-countable-set-of-reals-outside-itsel/

Comment: @gowers This might answer (2) negatively. Suppose $T \models (X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q})$. Then $T \models (X \in H(\omega_{1}))$, since $\mathbb{Q} \in H(\omega_{1})$ which satisfies Replacement; hence $X$ is countable.

Answer (score 18):

There is a surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\omega_{1}$, but none from $\omega$.

(Edit: I see, buried amongst the many comments, that bof suggested this proof for $P(\omega)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$; sorry.) I learnt it like this (from Komjath and Totik), using series expansions of reals.

Let us say that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ codes $\alpha < \omega_{1}$ if $\langle \omega, < \rangle$ is a well order of type $\alpha$, where $i < j \in \omega$ iff the $2^{i}3^{j}$-digit of $x$ is $1$.

Map $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\omega_{1}$ by sending $x$ to $\alpha$ if $x$ codes $\alpha$, otherwise map $x$ to $0$. Map to $0$ any real $x$ that does not code an ordered set, or that does code an ordered set but it is not well-ordered.

Comment: Yes, but without invariably proving that $\Bbb R$ and $\cal P(\Bbb N)$ have the same cardinality, how would you prove it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila You can get the surjection from the fact that every countable ordinal is isomorphic to a relation on $\omega$, and hence coded by a real.

Comment: @Joel, so you need to know that the reals the $2^\omega$ are equipotent. That was my point.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, all you need is that the Cantor set exists. Why would you need that $\mathbb R$ injects into $2^{\mathbb N}$?

Comment: @Andres: Fine, so if $2^\omega\leq\Bbb R$, why do we have to work anymore than that? This suffices to show that $R$ is uncountable, since there is no surjection from $\omega$ onto $2^\omega$.

Comment: (@Asaf Yes, of course. I was only commenting on the proof of the existence of the surjection onto $\omega_1$.)

Comment: This proof seems to me to be  genuine proof without diagonalization! Doesn't this completely answer the question?

Comment: @Joel: Does the proof using $\aleph_0$-categoricity of DLO use diagonalization somewhere? (Just curious to hear your opinion.)

Comment: I thought I had said in the comments on Bill's answer that I thought it did.

Comment: But how do we know that an uncountable ordinal exists in the first place without diagonalization?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow An uncountable well-ordering exists by considering the set of isomorphism types of well-orderings of sets of naturals with respect to initial segment embedding, and replacement lets us turn that into an ordinal (although we don't even need to do that for this proof). Diagonalization isn't relevant to constructing an uncountable ordinal.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Is this essentially the same as the pf of Hartog's Thm? That proof feels very diagonalization-ish: it basically says to consider the ordinal $\alpha$ consisting of all ordinals that inject into $\omega$, and then argues that $\alpha$ must differ from all such ordinals b/c otherwise we'd have $\alpha \in \alpha$ and thus $\alpha < \alpha$. I see that it is different from many other diagonalizations in that it avoids AC, and I wish I could put my finger on it more concretely, but it still feels diagonalization-ish.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I don't think there's anything diagonalization-y here. Maybe it helps to phrase the conclusion as getting an infinite descending sequence in a (putative) ordinal?

Answer (score 18):

In the paper [An Unusual Proof that the Reals are Uncountable](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0446)
a proof of the uncountability of the reals is given which is adapted from one of Bourbaki's proofs in "Fonctions d'une variable réelle". Let me give it here:

Suppose $R$ was countable. Then there is a function
$a(x) : R → R$ such that:

1. $a(x) > 0$ for all $x$,
2. the sum of the $a(x)$ on any finite set is $≤ 1.$

(take $a(x) = 2^{-n}$
if $x$ is the $n$’th element in the counting).

Now, define for any  $S\subseteq R$,

$m(S)=$ the supremum of the sums of $a(x)$ on finite subsets of $S$.

Then surely $0 ≤ m(S) ≤ 1$ for any $S$.
Define:

$c := \sup\{x: m(-\infty, x)>x  \}$

Since $a(c) > 0,$ there is a $y$ such that $y > c − a(c)$ and $m( − ∞, y)> y$, thus $y ≤ c$. Now, since $y ≤ c$, $( − ∞, y)$ does not contain $c$. But $( −∞, y + a(c))$ contains
$c$ because $y > c − a(c).$ So by the definition of $m(S)$,

$m( − ∞, y + a(c)) ≥ m( − ∞, y) +a(c) > y + a(c)$,

But $y + a(c) > c$  a contradiction.

Comment: This is also mentioned in @Ralph's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47019), without the details.

Answer (score 12):

Cantor gave several proofs of uncountability of reals; one involves the fact that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence (thus being related to the nested interval property). All his proofs are discussed here:

[MR2732322](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2732322) (2011k:01009)
Franks, John:
Cantor's other proofs that R is uncountable. (English summary)
Math. Mag. 83 (2010), no. 4, 283–289.

Answer (score 8):

A nice proof based on the property that each bounded subset of the reals has a supremum can be found in [Levy - An unusual proof that the reals are uncountable](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0446).

Answer (score 6):

What about the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem)? It implies that every complete metric space without isolated points is uncountable. But of course, *every* proof uses some construction or rather characterization of $\mathbb{R}$. I think Cantor's diagonal argument is not bad at all.

Comment: Thanks. Looking just for some variants, I believe the diagonal argument is also interesting.

Comment: The proof of the Baire Category Theorem I have in mind is a fairly direct generalisation of Cantor's Diagonal Argument. 

Comment: Yes, the Baire category argument is (I believe) equivalent to the axiom of dependent choice in ZF, and thus non-constructive. 

Comment: Similarly, we can use the existence of (countably additive) Lebesgue measure to conclude that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.  Or on $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ the existence of the (countably additive) product measure.  Or, from probability theory, the existence of an i.i.d. sequence of non-trivial random variables.


Comment: If you unwind the Baire Category proof of uncountability, it actually turns into a diagonal argument after all.  Given any sequence $(x_i)$ of real numbers, you argue that the intersection over $i$ of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_i\}$ is dense, by BCT, hence non-empty.  The standard proof of BCT constructs an element of this intersection by first taking a ball contained in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_0\}$, then a sub-ball of this contained $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_1\}$, and so-on.  In other words, we construct a real by a countable sequence of approximations, [cont’d]

Comment: with the $n$th approximation ensuring that the resulting limit is not equal  to $x_n$.  So this is a version diagonal argument in the same sense that the nested limit theorem is.

Comment: @Todd: The abstract Baire category argument requires (dependent) choice, but for the reals can be done without requiring extra choice.  Instead, enumerate the rationals, then when asked to "choose" a point in a given open interval, choose the first rational in that interval.


Comment: Essentially the same point as Peter has just made, but Baire category in the reals uses nested closed intervals. In fact, if you apply it to the complements of countably many singletons, you get exactly the proof discussed in the post.

Comment: Gerald: you're right, although one considers arbitrary sequences, not just enumerations of the rationals. 

Comment: Still, rather than fiddling with decimal expansions, this approach shows that for any countable set of reals the complement is open and dense. That makes one less likely to fall into the newbie trap of saying "great, I missed one (or) more, just interleave them in the list or put them in a second list." I like Gowers' remark that having a sequence is important.

Answer (score 6):

Cantor's [original proof of uncountability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_uncountability_proof) of the reals did not explicitly mention diagonalization.  Nor did it use decimal digits.

Comment: Unfortunately, this proof uses a diagonal argument.

Comment: +1. I consider this to be a very different proof. It is constructive, or can be made so with little change. The diagonal argument actually proves the uncountability of 2^N, and no effective bijection between R and 2^N exists. 

Comment: @Daniel : I am not sure I understand what you mean. The proof uses a diagonal argument. The typical diagonal argument proofs *are* constructive. And it is easy to describe explicitly bijections between ${\mathbb R}$ and $2^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: This information and the corresponding wikipedia link are already contained in my comment above :-)

Comment: Michael, if you reflect upon it, you will see that the two arguments are fundamentally identical. Prescribing the successive digits of a real to have certain values is the same thing as placing the resulting real in certain intervals.

Comment: But is the proof using shrinking intervals a "diagonal argument" in the sense in which the proof that every set has more subsets than member is a diagonal argument, or in the sense in which the usual proof of the unsolvability of the halting problem is a diagonal argument?

Comment: @Andres:  The bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{P}\mathbb{N}$ is *not* constructive in the avoids-excluded-middle/acceptable-to-intuitionists sense.  Although you can explicitly describe what appears to be a bijection, proving that it's defined everywhere requires excluded middle.

In contrast, Cantor's nested-interval argument is acceptable.  (Brouwer couldn't help complaining about how Cantor explained it and cleaning it up to his satisfaction, but he didn't change the argument.)  This doesn't mean that it's not also a diagonalization argument, but it's a different one.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins : "Diagonal" in this context mean the set $\{(x,x) : x\in\text{some specified set} \}.$ So the question is how to view it that way.

Answer (score 6):

As Andres implicitly pointed out, we may avoid diagonalization by working with ordinals directly.  We can appeal to Hartogs' Theorem to show that there is an ordinal $\beta$ that does not inject into $\omega$.  It is then easy to verify that the least such $\beta$ will be $\omega_1$ (i.e., the set of all countable ordinals).  Now using Choice, we can construct an injection $f: \omega_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\omega)$ by encoding each countable ordinal as a unique subset of $\omega$.  This can be done by letting $\langle f_{\alpha}| \alpha < \omega_1\rangle$ be a sequence such that each $f_{\alpha}$ is a bijection from $\omega$ into $\alpha$ and then defining $f(\alpha) = $ {$\langle m, n\rangle| f_{\alpha}(m) < f_{\alpha}(n)$} where $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle: \omega \times \omega \rightarrow \omega$ is the Cantor pairing function.  This completes the proof as if there were an injection from the powerset of $\omega$ (or the Reals) into $\omega$, then there would be an injection from $\omega_1$ into $\omega$.

It is worth noting that in a standard proof of Hartogs' Theorem, we use the fact that an ordinal cannot be a member of itself ($\beta \notin \beta$).  But because ordinals are well-ordered by the $\in$ relation, we can prove this fact without appealing to Foundation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to work with surjections instead of injections? There is a surjection from $\mathcal P(\omega)$ to $\omega_1$, there is no surjection from $\omega$ to $\omega_1$, therefore $\mathcal P(\omega)$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 5):

I have the following candidate:
[Fornasiero - Tame structures and open cores](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3557), section 7.4.
Notice that in the setting of the article one cannot use diagonalization.

Answer (score 5):

How about this proof?

Let $\omega_1$ be the set of all ordinal numbers which are countable. Then $\omega_1$ is itself ordinal number, but it must be uncountable, otherwise it would contain itself. We will now find the subset of $2^\Bbb N$ (which, as we know, is equipotent with $\Bbb R$)  which has power at least that of $\omega_1$.

Let us fix any coding of binary relations as infinite binary strings. Now, for infinite countable ordinal $\alpha$, let $D_\alpha$ be subset of $2^\Bbb N$ consisting of these strings, which code relations which are well-orders with order type $\alpha$. Then all of $D_\alpha$ are non-empty disjoint. We know that union of uncountably many disjoint non-empty sets is uncountable, so we can take $\bigcup_{\omega\leq\alpha<\omega_1} D_\alpha$, which is uncountable subset of $2^\Bbb N$, thus the latter set is uncountable, as is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The last part relies on the fact that a partition of a set never has more parts than there are elements in the underlying set. This is actually not necessarily true! That is, that fact is a weak form of the Axiom of Choice as [explained by Dr. Strangechoice](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22927/why-worry-about-the-axiom-of-choice/22935#22935). That said, the argument does work to show that $|2^{\mathbb{N}}| \gt \aleph_0$ since the contrary assumption $|2^{\mathbb{N}}| \leq \aleph_0$ entails that $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is wellorderable.

Comment: I was wondering if I can come up with a proof which both doesn't use choice and doesn't use contradiction, but it looks like this argument won't exactly work.

Comment: The issue is that "uncountable" is a negative statement and the *natural* way to prove a negative is by deriving a contradiction from the positive statement. Note that this is [not a proof by contradiction](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/), which consists of proving a positive by deriving a contradiction from the negative...

Comment: I think this answer goes in the right direction. It seems to me that a way (if not *the* way) to give a precise meaning to the original question  is proving $|\mathbb{R}|>|\mathbb{N}|$ in an axiomatic context where one can't prove $|\mathbb{R}|=|2^\mathbb{N}|$, which is a consequence of the diagonal argument.

Comment: @François, the proof is choice free. Only the conclusion that $\aleph_1\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ uses choice. However if you already know that $\Bbb R$ and $\cal P(\Bbb N)$ are equipotent, why so you need to continue? Cantor's theorem, the general one, is easier.

Answer (score 5):

I like the following geometric argument.

**Lemma.** For any convex compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with non-empty interior there exists a point $x$ on the boundary such that the support line in $x$ is unique.

**Proof.** Let $p$ be interior point, and $x$ the closest to $p$ point of the boundary. Since the circle centered in $p$ and passing through $x$ is contained in $K$, the onliest support line in $x$ is perpendicular to the segment $px$.

Now assume that the points of $[0,1]$ are enumerated as $r_1,r_2,\dots$. Consider the convex function $f(x)=\sum_n 2^{-n}\max((r_n-1)x,r_n(x-1))$. Consider the set $K$ bounded by the graphs of $f$ and $-f$: $K=\{(x,y):f(x)\leqslant y\leqslant -f(x),x\in[0,1]\}$. It is easy to see that it does not satisfy the conclusion of Lemma, since the left derivative of $f$ is strictly smaller than the right derivative at any interior point of the segment $[0,1]$, and the derivative at endpoints is finite.

Comment: I think you need the Nested Interval Theorem referred to in the question to prove that the $x$ in the Lemma exists.

Comment: Definitely I need (or some other variant of completeness axiom.) This proof is not the best in logical or set-theoretical sense.

Answer (score 4):

One can use the following theorem:

> Every countable dense linear order without endpoints is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

Since the real numbers are ordered densely and without endpoints, if $\Bbb R$ was countable it was isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

However $\Bbb R$ is order-complete, and $\Bbb Q$ is not. So they are clearly not isomorphic, and therefore $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.

Comment: Isn’t this basically the same as Bill Johnson’s answer?

Comment: Oh crap, I didn't even see that. I feel bad now...


Answer (score 4):

Just to add a couple of references:

1. John Franks' paper titled "Cantor’s Other Proofs that R Is Uncountable" is available at https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/002557010X521822 (unfortunately, not for free)
2. and Akihiro Kanamori & David Pincus' paper titled "Does GCH Imply AC Locally" is available at http://math.bu.edu/people/aki/7.pdf (for free).
3. You might also like looking at "Diagonalizing by Fixed-Points" by "Ahmad Karimi & Saeed Salehi" (available at arxiv.org) where some of the above mentioned proofs have been discussed.

Answer (score 4):

Today I attended a lecture, and this question was asked, after the talk, I realized the following proof, that might be interesting, at least for set theorists!!!:

> **Theorem** (Cantor): The set of real numbers is uncountable.
>
> *Proof:* Suppose not. Let $M$ be a countable transitive model of enough of ZFC such that $\mathbb R\in M$.
> By our assumption $\mathbb R\subseteq M$.
>
> Let $\mathbb P=\operatorname{Add}(\omega,1)$ be the Cohen forcing for adding a new real, let $G\subseteq\mathbb P$ be generic over $M$ and let $r=\bigcup G$.
>
> Then:
>
> 1. $r\notin M$, as otherwise $G=\{r \restriction n: n<\omega  \}\in M$ which is not possible
> 2. $r\in\mathbb R\subseteq M$
>
> A contradiction.

Comment: The problem here is that we use such heavy machinery that it's not clear if we used the uncountability of the reals somewhere in the process. If we did, the proof is circular.

Comment: This is cute, but likely diagonalization is recognizable arguing that generics exist and don't belong to the ground model.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo  At least not visible. To show the existence of generic filter, we just count dense sets and build the filter inductively. To show the generic filter is not in the ground model, we just use the fact that its complement is dense.

Answer (score 3):

Matthew Baker ([Uncountable Sets and an Infinite Real Number Game](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~mbaker/pdf/mathmag_baker.pdf), Mathematics Magazine 80, no.5 (December 2007), 377-380) has proposed an amusing proof.

A subset $S$ of $[0,1]$ is being given.
Let Alice and Bob play the following game, in which they successively choose
elements of $[0,1]$. Alice begins with $a_0=0$, Bob with $b_0=1$. At the $n$th stage, Alice chooses $a_n$ such that $a_{n-1}<a_n<b_{n-1}$; then Bob chooses $b_n$ such that $a_n<b_n<b_{n-1}$. The sequence $(a_n)$ has  a limit $\alpha$ in $[0,1]$,
and Alice wins if $\alpha\in S$. Otherwise, Bob wins.

If $S$ is countable, then Bob has a winning strategy. Given an enumeration $(s_n)$ of $S$, it consists in choosing $b_n=s_n$ at the $n$th stage,
if this is a legal move, and any other choice otherwise.
One checks that $\alpha\not\in S$.

But if $S=[0,1]$, then Alice wins, obviously. Hence $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: This is exactly the argument of nested intervals. By the way, the fact that Bob might not have a winning strategy doesn't mean that Bob has to lose.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the following proof mentioned, which I learned from Hai Dang at Mississippi State.

Suppose the reals are countable, and let $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ be an enumeration.  For each $j$, let $I_j$ be an interval centered at $a_j$ and having length $1 / 2^j$.

Since the sequence $\{a_j\}$ enumerates the reals, it follows that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty I_j = \mathbb{R}$.  But since the sum of the lengths of the $I_j$ is the geometric series 
$$ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j} = 1,$$ 
this is nonsense.

(Pretty much the same proof yields that $[0,2]$ is uncountable.)

There's probably a relation with the outer measure proof previously posted, but this one seems more concrete.

*Update:*  Two extended comments:

1) As mentioned below in my comment below, proving that [0,2] can't be covered by open intervals of length summing to 1 is easily done with compactness.  I didn't quickly see how to prove it without compactness.  And of course compactness of a closed interval uses the Nested Interval Theorem, as the original poster was trying to avoid.

2)  I presented a proof along these lines in an Analysis I class.  I liked how it came out a great deal, because it gave me a good reason to show students a typical application of compactness.  Compactness is abstract and difficult for beginning students to grasp, and I usually find it difficult to find good applications.  Students (or at least some of them) seemed to like this one a fair bit.

Comment: When you say "this is nonsense" you need explanation.  One explanation is existence of Lebesgue measure.  What you show is: a countable set has measure at most $1$.  You also need: the real line has measure ${}> 1$.  But (so far) you have not proved that.

Comment: I agree there's a detail there, but I think it's straightforward.  Measure theory makes it immediate, but isn't necessary.  For example, if you use open intervals, you could take a finite subcover of [0,2] by compactness.  Now you have a finite set of intervals with total length < 1, which cover an interval of length 2.