# Reference for Diagonalization Trick

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ho.history-overview

There is a standard trick in analysis, where one chooses a subsequence, then a subsequence of that... and wants to get an eventual subsubsequence of all of them and you take the diagonal.  I've always called this the diagonalization trick.

I heard once that this is due to Cantor but haven't been able to find a reference (all searches for diagonal and Cantor lead to his argument about the uncountability of [0,1].

Does anyone have an exact reference?

Thanks.

B.

Comment: Reed & Simon [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=78ROoxSZNl8C&pg=PA28) ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's only the *idea* of diagonalization that is due to Cantor (in his proof of uncountability of $[0,1]$) and its particular manifestation for iterated subsequences was due to someone else later.

Comment: This isn't really a "[diagonalization argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)" in the modern sense used by logicians, though it does share some key ideas. Rosenthal has called this type of argument "Ramsey's Theorem for Analysts", see [my answer here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/12228), so it could as well be called a "Ramsey trick".

Answer (score 12):

From [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=3RLGKcEjVIoC&pg=PA81), it sounds like a very early instance is in Ascoli's proof of his theorem: pp. 545-549 of *Le curve limite di una varietà data di curve*, Atti Accad. Lincei **18** (1884) 521-586. (Which, alas, I can't find online.)

Note that this predates Cantor's [argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) that you mention (for uncountability of [0,1]) by 7 years.

**Edit:** I have since found the above-cited article of Ascoli, [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=jRszAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA521). And I must say that the modern diagonal argument is less "obviously there" on pp. 545-549 than [Moore](http://books.google.com/books?id=3RLGKcEjVIoC&pg=PA81) made it sound. The notation is different and the crucial subscripts rather hard to read, so at first sight I feel the need for a native Italian speaker to help spot where precisely Ascoli passes to the diagonal sequence (as I guess he must somehow)...

(One may also consult a self-summary of the article in Rend. Reale Istituto lombardo di scienze e lettere **21** (1888) 365-371 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=K8AWAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA365).)

Comment: You may want to see [this](http://mathoverflow.net/a/23970/6085) as well. Du Bois-Reymond's paper is from 1875, and it is a very similar diagonalization argument to the "trick" the question refers to.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks, I guess you mean the footnote on [p. 365 of this long paper](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0008). You made me realize that there is a whole literature on this; e.g. the question whether du Bois-Reymond anticipates Cantor (or perhaps rather Ascoli) is interestingly debated [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=JjQrpYswtYEC&pg=PA570) and [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=wEj3Spept0AC&pg=PA187).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler, it is one of the most stunning pieces of argument out there, so it is rather natural that its genesis attracts a lot of interest.