# question about  tensor of two fields 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, $L$, $H$ extension fields of $k$, and $G=L\otimes_k H$. I wonder why (I want to know the proof but I can't find) the prime ideal of $G$ must be maximal, and its properties:

a) if $L$ is separable over $k$, then $G$ is reduced.

b) if $L$ is algebraic and purely inseparable over $k$, then $G$ has a unique prime ideal.

Comment: When $L$ is of finite degree, (a) is a straightforward exercise using the primitive element theorem, the CRT, and some basic facts about tensor products. As such, I don't think it's appropriate for the site. For arbitrary algebraic $L$, the same result follows because $L\otimes_kH$ is the union of the reduced rings $F\otimes_kH$ with $F$ a finite subextension of $L/k$ (this follows from flatness and what it means to be algebraic). The statement about prime ideals, at least in the case $L/k$ finite, is a fact about artinian rings.  

Comment:  Thank you !And what about the prime ideal in the case L/k inifinite 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For (a): a field extension $L/k$ is separable is $L$ is a separable algebra, that is, if $L\otimes K$ is a semisimple algebra for all field extensions $K/k$. In particular, if $L$ is separable over $k$ and $K$ is an extension of $k$, then $L\otimes K$ will have no nilpotent elements because it is semisimple.

For details, see for example, Pierce's beautiful book Associative algebras.

For (b), for which the argument is more elaborate, see Jacobson's *Lectures in Abstract Algebra*, vol. 3, where the result is part 3 of Theorem 21; he does without algebraicity, by the way.

Answer (score 6):

Dear TOM,

**Ad (a)** This is the definition of separable! An (arbitrarily big) extension $L/k$ is said to be separable if for any field extension $H/k$ the algebra $G=L\otimes_k H$ is reduced i.e, without non zero nilpotents. This is the definition given by Bourbaki, in *Algebra* Chapter V, §15. Clearly this answer to your question would be idiotic  if I didn't give you criteria for being separable. Here they are. Let $L/k$ be a field extension.

I) if $char (k)=0$, then $L$ is always separable

II) If $char(k)=p> 0$ , then the following are equivalent:

$\quad$ a) the extension $L/k$ is separable

$\quad$ b) there exists a $k$-basis $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ of $L$ seen as a $k$ vector space such that $(a_i^p)_{i\in I}$ is $k$- linearly free

$\quad$ c) in an algebraic closure $L^{alg}$ of $L$, the subextensions $L$ and $k^{\frac{1}{p^\infty}}$ (purely inseparable closure of $k$) are linearly disjoint

$\quad$ d) for every subextension $M$ of $L$ ($k\subset M\subset L$) which is of finite type over $k$ ( as a field extension ! ) there exists a finite transcendence basis $m_1, m_2,...,m_s$ of $M/k$ such that the extension $M/k(m_1, m_2,...,m_s)$ is finite and separable in the elementary sense of galois theory (the  minimal polynomial of every element has simple zeroes)

**Ad (b)** An extension $L/k$ is said to be primary if it is separably closed in the sense that every element in $L$ which is algebraic and separable over $k$  (minimal polynomial has simple zeroes ) already is in $k$. This is the case in your question: a purely inseparable extension is primary. The main result on primary extensions is that the tensor product of a primary extension with any extension has irreducible spectrum i.e. that its nilpotent radical $N=\sqrt{0}$ is prime. To conclude that $N$ is the only prime ideal of $G=L\otimes_k H$ it suffices to show that $G$ has dimension zero.This follows from a result to be found in a surprising place: the $Errata$ to EGA IV, Quatrième partie, Remarque 4.2.1.4, page 349

**Grothendieck's best hidden result** If $L$ and $H$ are field extensions of the field $k$, 
the Krull dimension of their tensor product is given by

$$\operatorname{dim}(L\otimes_k H )= \min (\operatorname{tr.deg} L, \operatorname{tr.deg} H) $$

Comment: Dear Georges, I took the liberty of changing max to min: if $H=k$   then $L\otimes_k H\simeq L$ is a field, so it has Krull dimension 0, and similarly for $H/k$ algebraic (unless there is an error in the erratum, EGA confirms max). Also, huge +++ for "Grothendieck's best hidden result"! In my ignorance, I $\textit{falsely believed}$ (cf http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23568#23568) that the tensor product of fields always has Krull dimension 0, which falls apart immediately upon inspection.


Comment: Dear Victor, thank you for the correction: you are absolutely right, of course. Incidentally, I am quite moved by people who, as you just did, acknowledge their previous misconceptions. I think this honesty is worth infinitely more than any knowledge of the strange behaviour of fields. 

Answer (score 4):

For (b) recall that a prime ideal is the kernel of a map from
$G$ into a field. Such a field must be an extension field of
$H$ and the image of $G$ is generated by $H$ and the $p^{r_i}$-th roots
of certain elements $a_i$ of $k$ where $p$ is the characteristic. Thus
the image of $G$ is a purely inseparable extension of $H$ and so embeds in
the perfect closure $H^i$ of $H$. Now see that there can only one
such map from $G$ extending the identity on $H$.