# Derivative of Sum over Variable of derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series

I feel stupid for having to ask this, but does anybody have any idea how to handle
$$\frac{d}{x}\sum_{n=k}^{g(x)}f(n,x)?$$
Example:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=6}^{i^2+2i} \frac{1}{\ln{(i^2)}-\ln{\ln n}}.$$
If we were able to separate the summand into two functions, one with only $i$ as a variable, and one with only $n$ as a variable, this would be super simple.  But it is not always the case.  Any ideas?

Comment: I take it $i$ in your sum was meant to be $x$. Think about a simpler example, like ${d\over dx}(1+2+\dots+x)$, and you may see what's happening. 

Comment: @Gerry $1+2+\cdots+x$ is not a sum like the first one in this post. That is, unless $x$ is restricted to being an integer, and then I do not know the meaning of differentiation with respect to $x$. For $f(n,x)=n$ and $g(x)=x$, the resulting sum is $k+(k+1)+\cdots+\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: Didier, yes, I was hoping Alex would work out what you've put forward. What does one make of ${d\over dx}(1+2+\cdots+[x])$?

Comment: @Gerry Then I should have kept quiet. Sorry.

Comment: Didier, I didn't mean to criticize you, and you have nothing to apologize for. But where has Alex gone?

Comment: @Gerry No harm done. Just mentioned that I am all for the way you used to give the OP a hint without providing a complete solution right away. (But try to use this @ thing in your comments, it signals automatically the other person that you posted something for her...)

Comment: @Didier, does it? I didn't get any signal that you posted something for me, I just make a habit of looking at my most recent comments to see if anything has happened. 

Comment: The easiest way to handle something like this particular example, is simply to expand and derive term by term. I see what you are saying. THank you

Comment: I don't think that is what Gerry and Didier are saying. They are asking what, in your example, is the $x$ with respect to which you wish to derive.

Comment: @Alex, maybe you should think about the old joke which says that $x^2=x+x+\cdots+x$ with $x$ summands, so the derivative of $x^2$ is $1+1+\cdots+1$ with $x$ summands, which is $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reminds me uncomfortably about a remark that Terry Tao made in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40082/why-do-we-teach-calculus-students-the-derivative-as-a-limit/44572#44572) about the importance of teaching the derivative as a limit: at least one person tried to prove Fermat's Last Theorem by differentiating with respect to the exponent. It does not make sense.

The reason why it does not: the derivative is something that is properly defined for **real** (or complex) variables. If you're variable is an integer, derivatives will not make sense.

There may objects that are analogous to the derivative in some ways, but you cannot carelessly apply derivative rules.