# Is there a convenient differential calculus for cojets?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differentials, differential-calculus

I understand the basics of exterior differential geometry and how to do calculus with exterior differential forms.  I know how to use this to justify the notation d*y*/d*x* as a literal ratio of the differentials d*y* and d*x* (by treating *x* and *y* as scalar-valued functions on a 1-dimensional manifold and introducing division formally).  I would like to extend this to *second* derivatives.  Ideally, this would justify the notation d<sup>2</sup>*y*/d*x*<sup>2</sup> as a literal ratio.

I can't do this with the exterior differential, since both d<sup>2</sup>*y* and d*x* ∧ d*x* are zero in the exterior calculus.  It occurs to me that this would work if, instead of exterior differential forms (sections of the exterior bundle), I used sections of the cojet bundle (cojet differential forms).  In particular, while degree-2 exterior forms may be written in local coordinates as linear combinations of d*x*<sup>*i*</sup> ∧ d*x*<sup>*j*</sup> for *i* < *j* (so on a 1-dimensional manifold the only exterior 2-form is zero), degree-2 cojet forms may be written in local coordinates as linear combinations of d<sup>2</sup>*x* and d*x*<sup>*i*</sup> · d*x*<sup>*j*</sup> for *i* ≤ *j* (so on a 1-dimensional manifold the cojet 2-forms at a given point form a 2-dimensional space).

I know some places to read about cojets (and more so about jets) theoretically, but I don't know where to learn about practical calculations in a cojet calculus analogous to the exterior calculus.  In particular, I don't know any reference that introduces the concept of the degree-2 differential operator d<sup>2</sup>, much less one that gives and proves its basic properties.  I've even had to make up the notation ‘d<sup>2</sup>’ (although you can see where I got it) and the term ‘cojet differential form’.  I can work some things out for myself, but I'd rather have the confidence of seeing what others have done and subjected to peer review.

(Incidentally, I don't think that it is *quite* possible to justify d<sup>2</sup>*y*/d*x*<sup>2</sup>; the correct formula is d<sup>2</sup>*y*/d*x*<sup>2</sup> − (d*y*/d*x*)(d<sup>2</sup>*x*/d*x*<sup>2</sup>); we cannot let d<sup>2</sup>*x*/d*x*<sup>2</sup> vanish and retain the simplicity of the algebraic rules.  It would be better to write ∂<sup>2</sup>*y*/∂*x*<sup>2</sup>; the point is that this is the coefficient on d*x*<sup>2</sup> in an expansion of d<sup>2</sup>*y*, just as ∂y/∂x<sup>*i*</sup> is the coefficient of d*y* on *x*<sup>*i*</sup> when *y* is a function on a higher-dimensional space.  The coefficient of d<sup>2</sup>*y* on d<sup>2</sup>*x*, which would be ∂<sup>2</sup>*y*/∂<sup>2</sup>*x*, is simply d*y*/d*x* again.)

Comment: Could you provide an example of a calculation that you would like to be able to do or do more easily using such a calculus?

Comment: If you want to see a modern approach to the formal theory of PDE's (i.e., a cohomological approach to the Cartan-Kahler theorem, which was developed originally using exterior differential systems), look at the work of Hubert Goldschmidt, which builds on work by Spencer, Quillen, Guillemin, and Guillemin-Sternberg. See, for example, Chapters IX and X of the book "Exterior differential systems" by Bryant, Chern, Goldschmidt, and Griffiths.

Comment: I didn't want to get into the context, in case people started discussing that instead.  But there is a place to discuss that, in [this old thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40082/why-do-we-teach-calculus-students-the-derivative-as-a-limit/60505#60505).

I want to understand the theory behind a differentials-based approach to teaching freshman calculus, [as advocated by Dray and Manogue](http://www.physics.orst.edu/bridge/papers/CMJdifferentials.pdf) (pdf).  For first derivatives, I know how to make everything that they write formally correct.  But what about higher derivatives?

Comment: So here's a problem from freshman calculus:  Given that $y = x^3 - 3x$, for which values of $x$ does $y$ reach a local maximum or minimum?  We compute $\mathrm{d}{y} = (3x^2 - 3) \,\mathrm{d}{x}$, set this to $0$ and solve for $x$ to get two critical points, which we test using the second derivative.  Starting from $\mathrm{d}y$ above, we compute $\mathrm{d}^2{y} = 6x \,(\mathrm{d}{x})^2 + (3x^2 - 3) \,\mathrm{d}^2{x}$.  Plugging in $x = \pm{1}$, we get $\mathrm{d}^2{y} = \pm{6x^2} \,(\mathrm{d}x)^2$.  So $y$ has a local minimum when $x = 1$ and a local maximum when $x = -1$.

Comment: But I'm not sure what exactly I calculated there.  At the moment, to be sure that all of my steps are rigorous, I must divide by $\mathrm{d}{x}$ to get $\mathrm{d}{y}/\mathrm{d}{x} = 3x^2 - 3$, then differentiate that to get $\mathrm{d}(\mathrm{d}{y}/\mathrm{d}{x}) = 6x \,\mathrm{d}{x}$.  And the test isn't quite whether this is positive or negative; I must divide by $\mathrm{d}{x}$ again first.  So this application has lost much of the beauty of the differential-based approach.

Comment: As far as I know, using differentials do not provide any advantage when computing higher derivatives by hand. However, it *does* work beautifully in designing very simple recursive algorithms for computing higher derivatives of functions in software. Just search for descriptions of "automatic differentiation". It is a lot of fun to implement this using, say, C++ templates.

Comment: Could you add the definition for cojet? Or give a reference?

Comment: For jets, you can see Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_%28mathematics%29 but the basic idea is that a $k$-jet from $M$ to $N$ at a point $p$ is an equivalence class of smooth functions to $N$ from a neighbourhood of $p$, where two such functions are equivalent if their derivatives up to and including order $k$ are the same.  If $N$ is a vector bundle and we restrict to jets that map $p$ to $0$, then these form a vector space.  The $k$-cojet space at $p$ is the dual space, and these join to form a vector bundle whose sections I call the degree-$k$ cojet differential forms.

Comment: I'm pretty much restricting to the case where $M$ has $1$ dimension and $N$ is $\mathbb{R}$ (the trivial line bundle), but I would like to understand at least higher-dimensional $M$ (which is the usual context for exterior differential forms).  So far, I'm working things out for myself, but I'd hate to think that this is new.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but if $\Gamma(N)$ is the module of sections of a vector bundle over $M$ then $\Gamma(J^K(N)^*$ is "the same" as the module of linear differential operators from  $\Gamma(N)$ to $C^\infty(R)$. I.e. differential operators associating a function to a section. There is a differential d on these objects (if you allow the order k to change) called the Spencer complex (see for example the articles of Spencer on overdetermined system or the book cited by Dean or books by Vinogradov and Lychagin). But i don't know if this d is the one you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think Michael is mistaken. His comments seem on target. You might also want to take a look at Griffiths' work on doing calculus of variations with exterior differential systems.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: The $k$-jet bundle isn't a vector bundle for $k \geq 2$.  The fibers are vector spaces, but the transitions are not linear maps.  In particular, it cannot be dual to a co-jet vector bundle.

Comment: @Scott: Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think that the bundle of jets on a manifold with values in a vector space does have a canonical vector bundle structure (given by adding jets). In fact, the transition functions are linear, as pre-composing with a smooth map gives a linear map on jets. It seems that more generally the jets of sections of a vector bundle themselves form a vector bundle.

Comment: @Ricardo: Yes, you're correct that if you have a global trivialization of your vector bundle (i.e., taking jets with values in a vector space), you get an additive structure.  However, without a fixed trivialization, you don't get linear maps on jets of order greater than one.  For example, the transition between the north-pole and south-pole stereographic projections on $S^1$ produces a quadratic term on tangent 2-jet coordinates: if $z = 1/w$, then $d^2z = -\frac{2}{w^3} (dw)^2 - \frac{1}{w^2}d^2w$.  

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the following links help:
Gerd Kainz, Peter W. Michor: Natural transformations in differential geometry. Czechoslovak Math. J. 37 (1987), 584-607, accessible as scanned paper under:
http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/nat-transf.pdf.
A slightly more extended version is in chapter 8 of:
Ivan Kolár, Jan Slovák, Peter W. Michor: Natural operations in differential geometry. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, Heidelberg, New York, (1993), vi+434 pp.
which is accessible via 
http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, your example computation in the comments is a computation in the Hasse-Schmidt ring of a polynomial algebra.  Given a commutative ring $A$ and $A$-algebras $f:A \to B$ and $A \to R$, an order $k$ Hasse-Schmidt differential from $B$ to $R$ is a $k+1$-tuple $(D_0,\ldots,D_k)$ of $A$-module maps from $B$ to $R$ satisfying:

1. $D_i(f(a)) = 0$ for all $i \geq 1$ and all $a \in A$.
2. $D_i(b_1 \cdot b_2) = \sum_{j=0}^i D_j(b_1) D_{i-j}(b_2)$.

We write $Der^k_A(B,R)$ for the set of order $k$ differentials from $B$ to $R$.  There is a Hasse-Schmidt algebra $HS^k_{B/A}$ with universal $k$-derivation that represents the functor $Der^k_A(B,-)$, and its relative spectrum over $\operatorname{Spec} B$ is the relative $k$th jet space of $B/A$.  For example, $HS^0_{B/A} = B$, and $HS^1_{B/A} = Sym_B^*(\Omega_{B/A})$ yields the tangent bundle.  You can find this information in Vojta's [EGA-style exposition](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407113).

Concretely, here is your example: Let $A$ be a ring such as $\mathbb{R}$, and let $B = A[x]$.  It is not hard to show that $HS^k_{B/A} \cong B[x^{(1)},x^{(2)},\ldots,x^{(k)}]$, with canonical maps $y \mapsto y^{(i)}$.  In terms of ordinary differentials, we have $x^{(i)} = \frac{1}{i!}d^ix$, and in particular, if we were to write the higher Leibniz rule with differentials, we would need some $\binom{i}{j}$ factors.  At any rate, repeated use of the Leibniz relation yields $d^2(x^3-3x) = (3x^2-3)d^2x + 6x(dx)^2$.

If you want to differentiate something twice, you use the fact that for any $y$, $dy$ is equal to $d^0 y' dx$ for some $y' \in B$, then apply the quotient rule: $d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{dx\cdot d^2 y - dy \cdot d^2 x}{(dx)^2}$.  In particular, you find that $d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)/dx \neq \frac{d^2 y}{(dx)^2}$, because $\frac{d^2x}{(dx)^2} \neq 0$ in this ring.  If you really want the somewhat misleading notation $\frac{d^ky}{dx^k}$ to literally denote a $k$th derivative, you have to mod out by the ideal generated by $d^ix$ for $i \geq 2$.