# Etalé space construction for presheaves on a Grothendieck site

Tags: sheaf-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

As it is described for example in [Mac Lane-Moerdijk, Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, II.6.], one can construct the sheafification functor very lucidly by associating to a presheaf a certain bundle (cf. espace etale) and then taking its sheaf of sections.

This construction is outlined in the reference for presheaves $\mathcal{O}(X)^{op}\to Sets$ where $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is the category of opens for a topological space $X$.

Does this method work for presheaves $C^{op}\to Sets$ on a general small Grothendieck site, too, and is this written down somewhere?

(Let's assume also that the associated topos has enough points.)

Comment: Martin Brandenburg [mentioned this][1] as a "common false belief"—the problem is that we might have to take a colimit over an indexing category that is not essentially small.  But it should be possible to sheafify presheaves on most reasonable sites.  For example, the category of étale maps to a scheme is essentially small (I think), so this problem does not arise.


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23640#23640

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Of course, $C$ has to be (essentially) small.

Comment: See the first proof on p61 of Milne's book on etale cohomology for the etale site. Something similar may work in general provided there are enough points.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on what you mean by an étalé "space". As long as $C$ has a small set of topological generators (i.e. as long as $Sh(C,J)$ isn't too large to be a topos), there always exists a certain version of an étalé space: If $F$ is a sheaf on $(C,J),$ the slice topos $Sh(C,J)/F$ has a canonical étale projection  $$\pi_F:Sh(C,J)/F \to Sh(C,J).$$ This map is a local homeomorphism of topoi. This topos with this local homeomorphism is the étalé space of $F.$ Indeed, we may make this construction for each object $c \in C,$ call it $U(c):=Sh(C,J)/y(c),$ where $y(c)$ is the (possibly sheafified) Yoneda embedded object. Then, "sections of $\pi_F$ over $U(c) \to Sh(C,J)$" are in bijection with elements of $F(c).$ If the Grothendieck site $(C,J)$ happened to be the canonical site of a topological space, then each slice $Sh(C,J)/F$ is equivalent to sheaves on the étalé space of that sheaf, and the projection corresponds to the usual one. In particular, $U(c) \to Sh(C,J)$ corresponds to the inclusion of an open subset. So, this is reduces to the usual construction for spaces. Another example is, if $(C,J)$ were the small étale site of some scheme $S$, then each $Sh(C,J)/F$ is the small étale site of some algebraic space (with no seperation conditions) étale over $S,$ with $\pi_F$ corresponding to the étale map from this algebraic space to $S.$

Comment: Is there a citeable reference that discusses this?  See also https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/11283/etale-space/?Focus=84575#Comment_84575

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Eric Ahlqvist's [master thesis](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:938522/FULLTEXT01.pdf) summarizes the étalé space of an étale sheaf, which is subsequently referring to Milne's book.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: perhaps https://doi.org/10.2140/agt.2013.13.831, but David Cardechi is better qualified to point out exact references. :)