# Espace étalé for derived category

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, derived-categories, perverse-sheaves

It is known that for a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, we can associate $X_\mathcal{F}$, the étalé space of $\mathcal{F}$ over $X$ such that section of $X_\mathcal{F}$ coincides with section of $\mathcal{F}$.

Is it possible to generalize this concept to derived category of sheaves over $X$ or perverse sheaves over $X$?

There are similar questions asked before, see links below. Yet they focus on abstract nonsense argument. I would like to see concrete constructions specifically for derived category or perverse sheaves.

[Etalé space construction for presheaves on a Grothendieck site](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78681/etal%c3%a9-space-construction-for-presheaves-on-a-grothendieck-site)

[How to construct the espace étalé (space of sections) for an arbitrary category?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317101/how-to-construct-the-espace-%c3%a9tal%c3%a9-space-of-sections-for-an-arbitrary-category)

Comment: Are you aware of the Grothendieck construction (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction) ? You can do that for presheaves with values in $\infty$-groupoids. That somehow generalises the ordinary construction by putting automorphisms there. I'm however not aware of any construction that somehow would add a topology in that to get some kind of topological $\infty$-groupoid.