# Do all exact $1 \to A \to A \times B \to B \to 1$ split for finite groups?

Tags: homological-algebra, short-exact-sequences, finite-groups, gr.group-theory

Let $A$, $B$ be finite groups.  Is it true that all short exact sequences $1 \rightarrow A \rightarrow A \times B \rightarrow B \rightarrow 1$ split on the right?

In other words, do there exist finite groups $A$, $B$ and homomorphisms $f: A \rightarrow A \times B$, $g: A \times B \rightarrow B$ such that $1 \rightarrow A \rightarrow A \times B \rightarrow B \rightarrow 1$ is exact and there does not exist a homomorphism $h: B \rightarrow A \times B$ such that $g \circ h = \text{id}_B$?

An example when $A$, $B$ are not finite is given by $A = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$, $B = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $f((n_i)) = ((2n_i),0)$, and $g((n_i),(m_i)) = (\overline{n_1}, m_1, \overline{n_2}, m_2, \ldots)$.

Comment: Minor comment: Writing down the sequence $1 \to A \to A \times B \to B \to 1$ without specification of the morphisms always means that we consider the inclusion $A \to A \times B$ and the projection $A \times B \to B$. But anyway, you have clarified this in the second paragraph.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23640#23640 you write that "Every short exact sequence of [the form you mention] splits" is a false belief.

Comment: @A. Rex: Hehe, that's true.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is [true](https://doi.org/10.1515/JGT.2006.020) (1). It was extended to finitely generated profinite groups [here](https://doi.org/10.1515/JGT.2006.021) (2). Surprisingly, it is [also true](https://doi.org/10.1215/kjm/1250524308) in the category of  finitely generated modules over a Noetherian commutative ring (3).

(1) *Joseph Ayoub, The direct extension theorem, J. Group Theory 9 (2006) 307-316*.

(2) *Goldstein, Daniel, Guralnick, Robert, The direct product theorem for profinite groups. J. Group Theory 9 (2006), no. 3, 317-322.*

(3) *Takehiko Miyata, Note on direct summands of modules. J. Math. Kyoto Univ.
Volume 7, Number 1 (1967), 65-69.*

Comment: What I find surprising is that this was only proved 5 years ago.

Comment: Just to clarify, the answer to the question in the title is true, not the question in the second paragraph.

Comment: Thank you Hailong for bringing this to my attention!  Splitting of the sequence above on the right yields $A \oplus B$ as a (potentially non-trivial) semi-direct product.  But in fact we get even more, namely that the sequence splits on the left, meaning that $A \oplus B$ is actually a direct product.

Comment: Could you write down the references? One of the links is not working; after inquiry it's: Goldstein, Daniel, Guralnick, Robert
The direct product theorem for profinite groups. 
J. Group Theory 9 (2006), no. 3, 317-322.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that Ayoub's proof also applies to any group satisfying both chain conditions with only minor changes.  The only place his proof actually needs finiteness, rather than the analogous arguments with chain conditions, specifically is in results regarding the center $Z(G)$ and the abelianization $G/G'$, but these inherit the chain conditions and any abelian group satisfying both chain conditions is automatically finite.

Comment: Your hyperlink to (3) on Project Euclid is broken.

Comment: @KConrad, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80002/do-all-exact-1-to-a-to-a-times-b-to-b-to-1-split-for-finite-groups/80003#comment1081338_80003), @‍Glorfindel [fixed it](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/80003/3).  As mentioned at the post [Can (and should) Project Euclid links be replaced in bulk?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5301) linked in the edit summary, the fix can be done relatively routinely (by a human), if you want to do so when you notice it.