# if 0→A→A⊕B→B→0 is an exact sequence of finitely generated modules over a commutative Noetherian ring, then the exact sequence does split

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

[**Here**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/23640?noredirect=1#comment568499_23640), Martin Brandenburg says it is not true that "Every short exact sequence of the form $0 \to A \to A \oplus B \to B \to 0$ splits." Then Mohan says in comments that "As a positive result,

> If $0 \to A \to A \oplus B \to B \to 0$ is an exact sequence of finitely generated modules over a commutative Noetherian ring, then the exact sequence does split."

Mohan adds as an answer to my comment "The proof, while not trivial, can be worked out and I would be happy to post one somewhere (how?) if you so desire."
Now Mohan and other friends can you please...
Thank you.

Comment: It seems that a reference is given in Neil Epstein's comment which is 3 comments above Mohan's first comment in the answer you refer to. (Which is this, for people's convenience:  (Theorem 1 from T. Miyata, Note on direct summands of modules, J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 7 (1967) 65-69).)

Comment: On the analogous question for finite groups: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80002/

Comment: See my answer here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/167701/do-all-exact-sequences-0-rightarrow-a-rightarrow-a-oplus-b-rightarrow-b-ri/167706#167706