# When is a singular point of a variety ($\mathcal{C}^\infty$-) smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

If $X$ is a nonsingular  algebraic (or analytic) variety over $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$ then it is certainly $C^\infty$ over the reals.
The converse is  false for a silly reason : in the real or complex affine plane with coordinates $x,y$ the variety $x^2=0$ is  singular since it is not reduced, but set-theoretically it is the $y$-axis, a $C^\infty$ submanifold of the plane.
So let me concentrate on reduced varieties.

Over the reals you have the disturbing phenomenon that the  plane curve $C$ defined by $y^3+2x^2y-x^4=0$ is algebraically singular at the origin, but your favourite computer graphics system  won't show you that, because the curve is actually $C^\infty$.
Worse: it is the graph of a real analytic function! (I learned this example in Milnor's *Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces*)

I think this pathology is impossible over $\mathbb C$ but I cannot find a reference. So let me ask the official question:

**Can a reduced algebraic (or analytic) variety which has a singularity at a point be $C^\infty$ at that point?**

(Information on the more complicated real case welcome, of course)

**Edit** Francesco's answer shows that indeed a singular complex variety  cannot be smooth.
This is  quite interesting, because many books will give you the Jacobian criterion for a  map $\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C^k$ to define a submanifold but none (to my knowledge) adds that this Jacobian criterion also allows to prove *nonsmoothness* (modulo some technicalities), which is  paradoxically a more delicate question.

**Second Edit (June 29th,2012))**
Here is a  proof  more geometric than Milnor's that the curve $X$ defined by $y^3+2x^2y-x^4=0$ is an analytic submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.
The curve $X$ is actually rational: it is the image of $\mathbb R$ under $\phi (t)=(t(t^2+2),t^2(t^2+2))$.
The analytic morphism $\phi$ is injective, proper and immersive, hence an embedding into $\mathbb R^2$ with closed image $X$. [It  boils down to the fact that the polynomial $t^3+2t$ has positive  derivative $3t^2+2$ and is thus strictly increasing!]

Comment: +1 for your example: Pictures cannot always be trusted ..

Comment: This question and the answers are fantastic. MO at its very best. 

Comment: Thank you for this lovely question-and-answer.   There is (as it appears to me) one minor typographic error.  Namely, in regard to the second edit, the curve $X$ is in fact the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under $\phi(t)=(t(t^2+2),t^2(t^2+2))$, rather than the expression given for $\phi(t)$ (as can be verified by direct substitution).

Comment: Why didn't you consider in the first place the curve defined by $y^3 +x^2y-x^2y^2-x^4 = 0$? Doesn't it satisfy the same hyptohesis as your original curve? But the explanation why it is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ manifold is so much easier... ($y^3 +x^2y-x^2y^2-x^4 = (y-x^2)(y^2+x^2)$).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

*NB: This answer is directed to the questions about the real case, not the complex case, which was already treated by Francesco.  Added 5 July 2021:  Because of some questions I have received over the years since this was written, I have realized that there are a few places where the logic and flow are not completely transparent, so I have decided to make a few small changes to clarify those points.*

In some sense, the reason you are running into these 'problems' is that you are working with the ring of real polynomials rather than the ring of (germs of) real-valued analytic functions, which is also a UFD.  For example, it is not hard to show that there is a (unique) real-valued, real-analytic function $f$ defined in a neighborhood of $0$ and satisfying $f(0)=\frac12$ such that
$$
y^3 + 2x^2y-x^4 = \bigl(y - x^2f(x^2)\bigr)\bigl(y^2 + x^2f(x^2) y + x^2/f(x^2)\bigr),
$$
so $y^3 + 2x^2y-x^4$ is reducible in the ring of real-valued, real analytic functions defined on a neighborhood of the origin.  The curve $y = x^2f(x^2)$ is smooth (in fact, real-analytic, of course), but the $y$-discriminant of the quadratic factor is $x^4f(x^2)^2-4x^2/f(x^2) = -8x^2 + \cdots$, so the only real point of $y^2 + x^2f(x^2) y + x^2/f(x^2)=0$ near the origin is the origin itself.  (The quadratic factor is irreducible in the ring of real-valued analytic functions defined on a neighborhood of the origin.)

Thus, a more easily approached question is:  **Suppose that the origin is a singular zero of an *irreducible* element $f$ in the ring of real-valued analytic functions defined on a neighborhood of the origin (i.e., real-analytic germs).  Can the zero locus of $f$ be a nonsingular real-analytic hypersurface near the origin?**

The answer to this question is 'no' because near a nonsingular point of such a hypersurface, there will always be a real-analytic function $g$ that vanishes on it whose differential at that point is nonvanishing.  However, this will imply that $g$ is a factor of $f$, which is assumed to be irreducible.

There remains the question of whether the zero locus of an irreducible real-analytic germ $f$ that is singular at the origin could contain a *smooth* hypersurface passing through the origin.
The answer to this is also 'no', but it takes a little work to see this.

The case of a curve is not hard, using some standard facts about resolution of curve singularities:  If $f(x,y)$ is a nonzero, real-valued analytic function defined on a neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is irreducible in the ring of analytic germs at the origin and satisfies $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$, then the locus $f(x,y)=0$ cannot contain a smoothly embedded curve passing through the origin.

A sketch of a proof is as follows:  If the origin is not isolated, then $f(z,w)$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-valued analytic function defined on a neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$ that is also irreducible in this larger ring, and hence there is a neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$ such that, in this neighborhood, the locus $f(z,w)=0$ can be parametrized by an embedded disc in $\mathbb{C}$ in the form $(z,w) = (a(\tau),b(\tau))$ where $a$ and $b$ are analytic functions of $\tau$ for $|\tau| < 1$ with $a(0)=b(0)=0$.  By a (real) rotation, we can assume that $a$ vanishes to a lower order, say $k>1$, than $b$ does. Thus, we can reparametrize in $\tau$ so that $a(\tau) = \tau^k$ for some $k>1$.  In particular, the real locus will be parametrized by some curves of the form $\tau = \omega\,t$ where $t$ is real and $\omega^k = \pm 1$.  Choosing one such curve and replacing $t$ by $t/\omega$, we can assume that $(a(t),b(t))$ is real for all small real $t$, and that this parametrizes a 'branch' of the real locus that passes through the origin.  In particular, the coefficients of $b$ are real, so our curve is parametrized in the form
$$
(x,y) = \bigl(\ t^k,\ b_l t^l + b_{l+1} t^{l+1} + \cdots\ \bigr)
$$
where $l>k$ and, because of the embeddedness property of the disk, the greatest common divisor of $k$ and those $m$ for which $b_m\not=0$ must be $1$.  Thus, the curve is expressed in the form
$$
 y = b_l\ x^{l/k} + b_{l+1}\ x^{(l+1)/k} + \cdots
$$
where at least one of the exponents in this series is not an integer.  It follows that the function on the right hand side of this equation cannot be smooth at $x=0$, even though, since $l>k$, it is $C^1$.

One conclusion of all this is that, if $g$ is a real-valued *smooth* function on a neighborhood of $0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(0)=0$ and such that there exists a nontrivial real-analytic  $f$ defined on a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ such that $f\bigl(x,g(x)\bigr)\equiv0$ for $x$ in the domain of $g$, then $g$ must actually be *real-analytic* in a neighborhood of $0$.  (Note, however, that there do exist such 'real-analytically constrained' $g$ that, for some $m>0$, are $C^m$ but not $C^{m+1}$ at $x=0$.)

Now, an easy argument shows that this $1$-variable fact implies the corresponding $n$-variable fact:  If $g$ is a real-valued *smooth* function on a neighborhood of $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g(0)=0$ and such that there exists a nontrivial real-analytic $f$ defined on a neighborhood of $(0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\bigl(x,g(x)\bigr)\equiv0$ for $x$ in the domain of $g$, then $g$ must actually be *real-analytic* in a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.  (Basically, the hypotheses and the $1$-variable result imply that $g\circ x$ is real-analytic for any real-analytic germ of a curve $x:(\mathbb{R},0)\to(\mathbb{R}^n,0)$, and this easily implies that $g$ itself is real-analytic in a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Thus, we have the answer to the question **Suppose that the origin is a singular zero of an irreducible element $f$ in the ring of real-valued analytic functions defined on a neighborhood of the origin.  Can the zero locus of $f$ be a nonsingular *smooth* hypersurface near the origin?**

The answer is 'no', because *smooth* would imply *real-analytic*, and we have already seen that this cannot happen.

Comment: Thank you for this very interesting answer, Robert. I hadn't thought of checking whether $y^3 + 2x^2y-x^4$ is irreducible in the local real analytic ring. But is it possible that  your analytically  irreducible, analytically singular  germ $f$    nevertheless has a zero locus which is the germ of a $C^\infty$ manifold ?

Comment: @George:  I sidestepped that by asking whether the hypersurface could be 'nonsingular real-analytic'.  I believe, though, that the answer, even for 'smooth' is still 'no'.  I haven't tried to write down a proof, but, at least in the $n=2$ case (i.e., an equation $f(x,y)=0$), I think I see how to write down an argument that proves this, but let me get a chance to check the details.  Over the complex numbers, there is no doubt, but there is something to check in the real case.

Comment: @George:  I have now added information that answers the question in the smooth case that you wanted.

Comment: Dear Robert, could I be so bold as to suggest you  publish this ? Considering that  none of the numerous users  gave a reference, I would conjecture that your explanations are not in the literature . And since  my question was so naïve and basic,  I am pretty sure that many mathematicians will be interested in its answer. Whatever your decision, let me assure you of my admiration for your analysis and my gratefulness for the time you took to write  such a definitive answer .

Comment: @RobertBryant There is a pitfall in this excellent solution, namely $k$ and $l$ need not be coprime; instead $k$ must be coprime to at least one of the exponents in the power series expansion starting from $x^l$ (for otherwise we can reparametrize $u=t^k$). A counterexample is $(y-x)^2-x^3=0$.

Comment: @FanZheng:  Thanks for this comment.  It's a notation error:  I should have written 'the greatest comon divisor of those $m$ for which $b_m$ is nonzero' and not re-used the letter '$l$' (which I had already used).  I'll fix that.

Answer (score 46):

The answer is in fact **no**.

A complex variety $X$ can never be a differentiable manifold (not even of class $C^1$) throughout a neighborhood of a singular point.

You can find a proof in Milnor's book "*Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces*", Annals of Mathematics Studies **61**, remark at page 13.

Notice that $X$ can be a topological manifold (i.e., a manifold  of class $C^0$) in a neighborhood of a singular point. For instance, the cuspidal plane cubic $y^2z=x^3$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment:  I feel silly because Milnor's is book where I learned about the real algebraic counterexample and probably also where I learned about the result you mention. But I had forgotten about that part , hence my phrase " I think this pathology is impossible over $\mathbb C$ but I cannot find a reference". Anyway, thanks a lot, Francesco! (I'm still interested in results about the real case. Any idea?) 

Comment: Dear Gerorges, you are welcome. The real case seems more delicate. I do not have any idea now, I should think about it. 

Comment: For the real case, I believe it is necessary and sufficient that the singularit have a single real-sloped tangent vector, and the rest complex. Thus, for plane curves with singularities at 0, the minimal degree of monomials should be an odd number, and the polynomial generated by minimal-degree monomials should have a single real root in $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: @Will:  I don't understand your criteria or your conclusion.  For example, $y^3 - x^5=0$ seems to satisfy your criteria, but this curve is not smooth at the origin; it is $C^1$, but not $C^2$.  More generally, considering $y^3 - x^{3n\pm 1}$ some $n>1$, the real locus can be made to be $C^k$ but not $C^{k+1}$ for any $k$. 

Answer (score 7):

As Francesco Polizzi said, the answer is in fact no. Here, a more general answer.

Let $X\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a complex analytic set with $d=\dim X$ and $x\in X$ be a singular point, then:

1) there is no homeomorphism $\varphi:(X,x)\to (\mathbb{C}^d,0)$ such that $\varphi$ (resp. $\varphi^{-1}$) is differentiable at $x$ (resp. $0$), for a prove see the [Gau and Lipman's paper (1983)](https://eudml.org/doc/143042).

2) there is no bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism $\varphi:(X,x)\to (\mathbb{C}^d,0)$, for a prove see the Theorem 4.2 in the [Sampaio's paper (2016)](http://jtopol.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2016/07/27/jtopol.jtw014).

Let $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a real analytic set with $d=\dim X$ and $x\in X$ be a singular point, then there is no $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism $\varphi:(X,x)\to (\mathbb{R}^d,0)$, since two real analytic sets $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphic are real analytic diffeomorphic, see for example the Proposition 1.1 in the [Ephraim's paper (1973)](https://scholarship.rice.edu/bitstream/handle/1911/63100/article_RIP591_part2.pdf?sequence=1).

Answer (score 3):

For the real case, here's another
example: the graph in ${\mathbb R}^2$ of
  $ y = x (1 + x^2)^{1/3} $
is real analytic and is the
${\mathbb R}$-points of a
variety defined over ${\mathbb R}$,
but the origin is 
singular; the defining equation is
 $  y^3 = x^3 + x^5 $.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but, then again, the function $y^3-x^3-x^5$ is reducible in the ring of germs at $(0,0)$ of *analytic* functions (rather than polynomial functions).  Since $(1{+}x^2)^{1/3}$ is analytic on a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, we have that $y-x(1{+}x^2)^{1/3}$ is a factor of $y^3-x^3-x^5$ in that larger ring.  As I pointed out in my answer, the 'right' question is whether the zero locus of an *analytically* irreducible analytic germ $f$ can be smooth at a zero $z$ of $f$ if the differential of $f$ vanishes at $z$.

Comment: Yes, that's the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Just to be clear, I only wanted to reinforce your suggestion with an example where the transition from polynomials to real analytic functions was, I thought, easier to see.

Comment: One last comment: For more algebraically minded mathematicians, I wonder if Robert's suggestion could be accomplished using formal power series over ${\mathbb R}$.