# Categories that admit all products but not all coproducts

Tags: ct.category-theory, big-list

What are examples for categories that admit all products but not all coproducts.

Comment: The original question seems to have had four good answers. It was then edited to specify *finite* (co)products. I don’t think changing the question like that, after people have put in effort to answer the original question, is right. So I have rolled back to the original question.

Comment: Maybe it would be best to split into two questions. @YilmazCaddesi, please feel free to ask a separate question looking for examples of categories with finite products but not finite coproducts.

Comment: @Tim Campion: Thank you for the suggestion, I have posted a new question.

Comment: Just a note that the OP did ask the finite version over here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466751/categories-that-admit-all-finite-products-but-not-all-finite-coproducts

Answer (score 15):

Now that the question was changed to existence of *finite* (co)products, here is a well-known example: the category $\mathbf{Gp}_{\text{fin}}$ of finite groups has finite limits, but not finite coproducts. The problem is that the coproduct in $\mathbf{Gp}$ of two finite groups need not be finite; e.g. $C_2 \ast C_3 \cong \operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf Z)$. The coproduct of $C_2$ and $C_3$ in finite groups cannot exist, as $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ does not have a largest finite quotient.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example appearing 'in nature': the category $\mathbf{Sch}$ of schemes has arbitrary (small) coproducts (disjoint unions), but existence of (small) products is a subtle question (on the other hand, finite limits do exist, whereas finite colimits are subtle). For instance, the product $(\mathbf P^1_{\mathbf Z})^{\mathbf N}$ does not exist in $\mathbf{Sch}$; see [Stacks, Tag [078E](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/078E)].

As noted before, to get an example where products exist but coproducts do not, take the opposite category $\mathbf{Sch}^{\text{op}}$.

Answer (score 9):

- Jeremy Rickard gives a nice example of a (locally small) category with all small colimits but not all small limits in an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/184486) to [Cocomplete but not complete abelian category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112574/cocomplete-but-not-complete-abelian-category). His category is even abelian (and in particular has finite limits), so the failure to have all small limits must come down to a failure to have all small products. You can dualize his example.

To underscore Max New’s [point](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466707), there is some pressure in category theory for a category with all small limits to have all small colimits and vice versa. For instance, as Max New points out, this is the case when the category is small (and hence is a poset). It’s more generally true that if $\mathcal C$ is [accessible](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/accessible+category) (which includes most “categories of structures”), then it has all small limits if it has all small colimits (in which case the category is called *locally presentable*). So in some sense, you should expect the examples here to all be in some sense “artificial”.

On the other hand, I just remembered a good source of accessible categories with all products — if you take a locally presentable category $\mathcal K$ and then pass to a full subcategory $\mathcal L$ defined by some injectivity conditions (i.e. you have a set $I$ of morphisms $(A_i \to B_i)_{i \in I}$ such that $X \in \mathcal L$ iff for all $i$ and all maps $A_i \to X$, there exists a map $B_i \to X$ making the obvious triangle commute), then $\mathcal K$ has all products, but not all coproducts in general.

- For example, there are rings $R$ such that the category of injective $R$-modules (which always has all products) is not closed under coproducts. I don’t remember an example of this example offhand though….
- Even better — the category of free abelian groups has all small coproducts but not all small products. Similarly the category of free (nonabelian) groups has all small coproducts but not all small products. Dualize this.
- Actually — that’s true for almost any “category of algebraic structures” — the full subcategory of free algebras has all small coproducts, but almost never has all small products. Dualize this. (I suppose this is an instance of Alex Kruckman’s [example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466704) where you take all coproducts of copies of some fixed object — here the free algebra on one generator.)
- For example, the category of [extremeally disconnected spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space) has all coproducts but not all products.

Comment: The term colloquially used for rings $R$, injective left modules over which are closed under coproducts (or, nontrivially equivalently, closed under coproducts indexed by a set of cardinality $|R|$), is left *noetherian*.

Comment: @DenisT Thanks! Apparently this fact (injectives closed under coproducts iff Noetherian) is known as the [Bass-Papp theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173702/projective-and-injective-modules-direct-sums-and-products).

Comment: Another important family not yet mentioned are Cartesian closed categories, particularly those which are freely generated by simply-typed lambda calculi ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lambda-calculus#simply_typed_lambda_calculus)); coproducts are a separate ingredient not addressed by their syntax, but products are implied by the builtin curry ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/currying)). (This would have been an answer, but it fits in a comment!)

Answer (score 7):

If $X$ is a large set and $\mathsf{Set}$ is the category of small sets, then $\mathsf{Set}/X$ is small-cocomplete, but it fails to have a terminal object. Now dualize this.

Comment: What are large sets and small sets?

Comment: Relative to a universe...

Answer (score 6):

For the version of the question about finite products and coproducts:

- Any meet-semilattice that does not have joins. For example, a linear order with no least element (which has no empty join).
- Take any object $A$ in a category with all finite products and consider the full subcategory whose objects are all finite powers of $A$. This will usually fail to have coproducts. For example, the category of all finite sets whose cardinalities are powers of $2$.

For the version of the question about small products and coproducts:

- The second example generalizes easily to arbitrary powers. For example, the category of all sets of  cardinality $2^\kappa$ for arbitrary cardinals $\kappa$.
- I originally claimed that the first example above generalizes easily as well, to complete meet-semilattices, but Max New correctly points out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211111) that every complete meet-semilattice is a lattice. However, as Tim Campion also correctly points out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211116), a large semilattice may have all small meets without having all small joins. For example, the dual of the join-semilattice of all small subsets of a large set (which has no bottom element, hence no empty join).

Yet another naturalish example is the category of non-empty sets, which has all products but no initial object, hence no empty coproduct.

Comment: Every complete semilattice is a lattice: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suplattice

Comment: A large poset with all small intersections may fail to have large intersections and may fail to have all small joins. For example, the opposite of the poset of small subsets of a large set has all small intersections but does not have a bottom element.

Comment: @MaxNew and Tim Campion Yes, thanks for the correction. I've incorporated your comments into my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As the question is stated, there are actually no examples, at least assuming classical logic.

1. Classically, every small complete category is thin, i.e., a preorder with arbitrary meets. (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+small+category#in_classical_logic)
2. By the adjoint functor theorem, any preorder with arbitrary meets also has arbitrary joins. (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suplattice).

More concretely, if you have all meets, you can define an arbitrary join of a set $S$ to be the meet of all the upper bounds of the set $\bigvee S = \bigwedge \{y\in X | \forall s \in S. y \geq s \}$.

Of course if you change "all" to mean something more reasonable like "finite" or indexed by some other small cardinal, you can get many examples.

Alternatively you can look at constructive mathematics, where you can add as an axiom that such a non-trivial small complete category exists. This is modeled by e.g., realizability toposes (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/realizability+topos).

Comment: It’s standard in category theory to say that a category “has all limits / colimits” if it has all _small_ limits / colimits. So I think it’s quite standard to interpret the question as asking for a category with all small products but not all small coproducts. That said, you make a fair point.

Comment: @TimCampion Really?  It's standard that a "complete" category is one with all small limits, but I don't think I've heard "all limits" used to mean "all small limits" very often, if at all, at least not in published mathematics (as opposed to sloppy language in an informal conversation).  I see you got a bunch of upvotes, but do you or an upvoter have some references to point to?

Comment: @MikeShulman: As one of the upvoters on Tim’s comment — like you, I think in formal writing people are generally careful to say “small” when they mean it.  But in less-formal settings, I think of leaving out the “small” as very usual, and MathOverflow questions are sufficiently casual that I’d fully agree with Tim, by far the most natural reading of this question is with an implicit intended “small”.  Genuinely considering *all* limits/colimits is sufficiently unusual that I’d expect someone to explicitly flag it up if that was what they really meant.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks.  I guess that makes sense, although I think I would tend to draw the line on the other side of MathOverflow -- you have to phrase a question precisely if you want an answer to the question you meant to ask.  Also, a beginner who isn't so familiar with size questions might not know that the qualifier is important to emphasize or not.

Answer (score 2):

**Opposites of Kleisli categories.**

If C is a category with coproducts, and T a monad on C, then it is easy to see that the Kleisli category Kl(T) will inherit the coproducts from C. On the other hand, Kleisli categories generally don't have products. Try your favorite monads on **Set**, e.g. lists, probability distributions. The crucial idea is that products of free algebras aren't generally free. Now dualize this construction to answer your question.

*Why should you care about opposites of Kleisli categories?* This seems rather contrived after all. Here are some ideas:

- **Lawvere theories** are essentially opposites of Kleisli categories (restricted to finite sets). This fits the context of this question well: a Lawvere theory is freely generated under products from a single sort $1$. We should generally not expect this to have coproducts.
- Opposites of Kleisli categories of continuation monads are prime examples of Selinger's [**control categories**](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-structures-in-computer-science/article/control-categories-and-duality-on-the-categorical-semantics-of-the-lambdamu-calculus/6E2D15454999D091B25D02A0A0EF5A8A)