# Categories that admit all finite products but not all finite coproducts

Tags: ct.category-theory, big-list, limits-and-colimits, products

What are examples for categories that admit all finite products but not all finite coproducts?

(See also this question: [Categories that admit all products but not all coproducts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466703/categories-that-admit-all-products-but-not-all-coproducts) .)

Comment: This question already has an answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/466704/11540

Comment: Oh, and another answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/466711/11540

Why are these existing answers not good enough for you?

Comment: @DavidWhite To be fair, the OP posted a different question (without the “finite”) which got several answers. They then edited the question, adding “finite” and got a couple more answers to the new question. I rolled back to the original question, as I didn’t think it was right to change the question after getting good answers. The OP was then advised to post the revised question as a new question, which they have now done.

Comment: I think then some of the answers to the finite case should be deleted at the other question and re-posted here, by the original answerers

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, I knew that, and I think you did the right thing. But my question to the OP is, why ask the second question? If the goal was to get an example of a category with finite products but not all finite coproducts, then the OP already had two good answers to that. So, why ask? Is the goal a comprehensive list? I'm pretty sure there are infinitely many examples possible. I'd like to better understand the motivation.

Answer (score 3):

This thread was a bit awkward because [the OP asked a question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/466703/11540), got answers, then edited it to match the current question, got more answers, and then the edits were rolled back and the OP asked the second question here. So that this question doesn't linger forever unanswered, I'm creating a CW answer with the two answers from the other thread.

[From Alex Kruckman](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466704/11540)

For the version of the question about finite products and coproducts:

- Any meet-semilattice that does not have joins. For example, a linear order with no least element (which has no empty join).
- Take any object $A$ in a category with all finite products and consider the full subcategory whose objects are all finite powers of $A$. This will usually fail to have coproducts. For example, the category of all finite sets whose cardinalities are powers of $2$.

Yet another naturalish example is the category of non-empty sets, which has all products but no initial object, hence no empty coproduct.

--

[From R. van Dobben de Bruyn](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466711/11540)

Now that the question was changed to existence of *finite* (co)products, here is a well-known example: the category $\mathbf{Gp}_{\text{fin}}$ of finite groups has finite limits, but not finite coproducts. The problem is that the coproduct in $\mathbf{Gp}$ of two finite groups need not be finite; e.g. $C_2 \ast C_3 \cong \operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf Z)$. The coproduct of $C_2$ and $C_3$ in finite groups cannot exist, as $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ does not have a largest finite quotient.