# Does every convex polyhedron have a combinatorially isomorphic counterpart whose angles between edges are rational multiples of $\pi$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, polyhedra

After reading [these](https://mathoverflow.net/q/129677/33754) very interesting questions, I came up with another one:

- Does every convex polyhedron have a [combinatorially isomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#The_face_lattice) counterpart whose angles between all pairs of edges meeting at a common vertex are rational multiples of $\pi$?

Comment: In view of Mnev' universality theorem, there are rigid convex polytopes (in sufficiently high dimension) which do not have angles equal to rational multiples of $\pi$.