# How to introduce not-orthonormal base on Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, kernels

I read some tutorial papers and slide，and find that the bases on Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces always be orthonormal. For examples，you can refer to this link for the content about [Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229113/orthonormal-bases-on-reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces). What if the introduced base are not orthonormal? Any papers talk about this problems?

Comment: You need to be careful about what you mean by a "basis" when dealing with infinite-dimensional normed spaces: there are several different notions, and I think you should first look up which one fits your needs. Right now, since it is not clear if you know what a Schauder basis or an unconditional basis is, it is difficult to point you in an appropriate direction

Comment: In any case, if you are relatively inexperienced in mathematics, then perhaps you would do better to ask your question on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @YemonChoi, thanks for your comments. You can check the link I refer in my questions. What makes I confuse is that if I introduce a non-orthonormal to replace the basis ```e_m``` in Eq.(1) mentioned in the link. Then, if the kernel still has the original property like: ```()=⟨,⟩```