# Björner-Wachs theorem for posets admitting an EL-labeling

Tags: co.combinatorics, cohen-macaulay-rings

In the survey paper  [Poset Topology: Tools and Applications](http://www.math.miami.edu/~wachs/papers/toolnotes.pdf) by Michelle Wachs, there is the following theorem on p46:

> **Theorem 3.2.4** (Björner and Wachs [[40]](http://www.math.miami.edu/~wachs/papers/nonpure2.pdf)). Suppose $P$ is a poset for
>   which $\hat{P}$ admits an EL-labeling. Then $P$ has the homotopy type of a wedge of spheres, where the number of $i$-spheres is the number of decreasing maximal $(i+2)$-chains of $\hat{P}$.

The notation $\hat{P}$ means $ P \cup \{\hat{0}, \hat{1}\}$. The homotopy type of a poset $P$ is the homotopy type of the geometric realization of its order complex $\Delta(P)$.

Now let $P$ be a poset of order $n+1$ and length $0$ (i.e. just isolated points), then $\hat{P}$ admits an obvious EL-labeling with $n$ decreasing maximal $2$-chains. So by Theorem 3.2.4, $P$ should have the homotopy type of a wedge of $n$ number of $0$-sphere, i.e just one point, but it is not correct because it is a set of $n+1$ points.

I would need some clarifications about this inconsistency, in particular:.

**Question**: Is the statement of Theorem 3.2.4 correct if we assume that there is no isolated point?

*Remark*: If a poset admits an EL-labeling then it is Cohen-Macaulay (see [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/52.pdf)), and a poset is Cohen-Macaulay iff its [Stanley–Reisner ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanley%E2%80%93Reisner_ring) is a [Cohen-Macaulay ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Macaulay_ring).

Comment: Each zero sphere is a collection of 2 points, (one basepoint and one other point) and when you wedge $n$ of them together, you identify the basepoints, yielding $n+1$ points in total.

Comment: @Phil: Ok, I had a false belief about a 0-sphere. I just post http://mathoverflow.net/a/236771/34538