# The homology of the orbit space

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

Suppose we have an acyclic group $G$ and let $X$ be a contractible CW-complex such that $G$ acts freely on $X$ (we do **not** suppose that the action is proper). 
Is there a way to understand the homology $\mathrm{H}_{\ast}(X/G, \mathbb{Z})$ ?
We assume that the quotient space $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

For example if the action were free **and** proper then $$\mathrm{H}_{\ast}(X/G, \mathbb{Z})=\mathrm{H}_{\ast}(pt, \mathbb{Z})$$

**Edit:** Here is, I think, a more general question. Let $A$ be an abelian group. And let $G$ be a group such that $$\mathrm{H}_{\ast}(BG, A)=\mathrm{H}_{\ast}(pt, A)$$ 
Suppose that $X$ is a contractible CW-complex such that $G$ acts on $X$ freely. We assume that the orbit space $X/G$ is Hausdorff. What can we say about $\mathrm{H}_{\ast}(X/G, A)$ ?

**Edit 2 (2019 January 5-th):** May be the initial question sounds wild. I would be curious of an example  where $G$ is an acyclic group acting freely on a contractible CW-complex and $$\mathrm{H}_{\ast}(X/G, \mathbb{Z})\neq\mathrm{H}_{\ast}(pt, \mathbb{Z})$$ 
with $X/G$ Hausdorff.

Comment: Isn't $X/G$ just $BG$ in this case?

Comment: @leibnewtz In the case when the action is free and proper, yes. in my question I'm assuming that the action is free but not proper...

Comment: Can you assume that $G$ permutes the cells of any CW-decomposition of $X$? Or is that equivalent to $G$ being proper?

Comment: @ChrisGerig No, I'm not assuming that it permutes the cells...

Comment: A tangential basic question: Is properness of G-action (or Hausdorffness of X/G, or both) equivalent to $X\to X/G$ being a cover (for a free G-action)?

Comment: You ask "what can be said?" but there are really at least two things you might mean by that. Are you more interested in (1) conditions under which $H_\ast(X/G,\mathbb Z) = H_\ast(pt, \mathbb Z)$ (as has come up in the comments), or (2) a better understanding of what happens when $H_\ast(X/G, \mathbb Z) \neq H_\ast(pt, \mathbb Z)$? Do you have an example where $H_\ast(X/G,\mathbb Z) \neq H_\ast(pt,\mathbb Z)$ that you're particularly interested in?

Comment: @TimCampion I don't have a particular example! It seems to me that the second issue (2) is more interesting...

Comment: Why are we told that $X$ is a CW-complex?  If the action of $G$ on $X$ preserves the cells and is free, then surely it will have to be proper.

Answer (score 0):

*As per the comments, there is currently a paradox in the* first *paragraph, somehow depending on $BG$ (where $G$ is a topological group) versus $BG^\delta$ (where $G^\delta$ has the discrete topology). I do not yet know the flaw/resolution.*

I do not think properness is needed here, only that the (free) action is continuous. Since $X$ is a free $G$-space, there is a homotopy equivalence $EG\times_GX\simeq X/G$, and since $X$ is contractible there is a weak homotopy equivalence $EG\times_GX\simeq EG\times_G\lbrace pt\rbrace$. So in the notation of equivariant singular homology (the singular homology of the Borel construction)
$$H_\ast(X/G)\cong H_\ast^G(X)\cong H_\ast^G(pt)\cong H_\ast(G)\cong 0$$
where the last isomorphism is due to acyclicity of $G$.

Here is a special case: Assume $G$ also permutes the cells of some CW decomposition of $X$ (called a $G$-CW-complex). Then I can work with equivariant cellular homology, the definition in Brown's book *Cohomology of Groups* (chapter VII.7) which uses chain complexes. Since $G$ acts freely, it is the equivariant homology $H_\ast(X/G)\cong H_\ast^G(X)$. Since $X$ is contractible, $H_\ast^G(X)=H_\ast^G(pt)=H_\ast(G)$. Since $G$ is acylic, $H_\ast(G)=0$. This is a special case of the Cartan-Leray spectral sequence, I believe. (It might be the case here that $X\to X/G$ is a regular cover.)

Comment: Something is wrong here.  Consider the additive group $G=\mathbb{R}$.  Setting $X = \mathbb{R}$, the group $G$ acts freely and continuously on the contractible CW complex $X$ (but of course does not permute the cells in any CW complex structure).  The quotient $X/G$ is a single point, and thus all of its homology above degree $0$ vanish.  However, $H_1(G)  = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AndyPutman An acyclic group by definition has $H_k(G)=0$ for $k>0$.

Comment: Right, but in your first display you don't use the fact that $G$ is acyclic until the very last equality (and in my example the first and next to last items in your chain of equalities are not equal).

Comment: Maybe I can say something more detailed/helpful later, but I think the issue here is that the homotopy equivalence $EG \times_G X \simeq X/G$ requires that the map $X\to X/G$ is a principal $G$-bundle (maybe you can get away with a little less than that?). In Andy's example, where $\mathbb{R}$ is considered with the discrete topology and $H_1 (\mathbb{R})$ means the group homology, i.e. the homology of $B\mathbb{R}^\delta$, the map is a (trivial) principal $\mathbb{R}$ bundle (over a point) instead of an $\mathbb{R}^\delta$-bundle.

Comment: Note that the oft-repeated statement "If $G$ acts freely and continuously on $X$, then $EG\times_G X \simeq X/G$" can't possibly be true without some extra hypotheses, since adding more open sets to the topology on $G$ won't destroy either freeness or continuity of the action, and won't change $X/G$, but can change $EG$ quite drastically.

Comment: (This is a pet peeve of mine, generalizing the pet peeve discussed here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/40070#40070)

Comment: @ChrisGerig I guess there is a confusion in your terminology, if the action of G on X is free,it does not mean that X is a free G-space. A free G-space (in my sense) is a cofibrant object in the model category of G-spaces (and in particular the action is free). If X were free G-space and contractible, then X/G is a model for BG.

Comment: @GSM Would it be possible to formulate it without mentioning any model structures? I guess something like $G\times X\to X\times X$ being a cofibration? But what are they?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე unfortunately, I don't  know...