# Strongly simple fusion categories: the known examples?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories, morita-equivalence, drinfeld-center

A fusion category is called *simple* if its fusion subcategories are just $Vec$ and itself. Let us call a fusion category *strongly simple* if every fusion category Morita equivalent to it (i.e. same Drinfeld center up to equiv.) is simple.

**Question**: What are the known examples of strongly simple fusion categories?

Note that if $G$ is a finite group then $Rep(G)$ is simple iff $G$ is simple, but it is strongly simple iff $G$ is cyclic of prime order, because $Rep(G)$ is Morita equivalent to $Vec(G)$ whose fusion subcategories (up to equiv.) are $Vec(H)$ with $H<G$.

The Extended Haagerup fusion categories are strongly simple, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.06076) (by Grossman-Morrison-Penneys-Peters-Snyder) classifying their Morita equivalence class. I wrote [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/348447/34538) the explicit fusion matrices (it is easy to see that they are all simple).