# A fusion ring identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories

**Fusion rings**

I'll more or less stick to the presentation given in this question: [[1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344079/is-there-an-integral-fusion-ring-which-is-not-of-frobenius-type#comment880109_344079.)]

We define a fusion ring as follows: consider a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{B}$ with finite basis $\mathcal{B}=\{b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n}\}$. Equip this module with a binary product such that we get a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra $\mathcal{F}=(\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{B},\cdot)$ where $b_{1}$ acts as a multiplicative identity in the ring $\mathcal{F}$ and
\begin{equation*}b_{i}\cdot b_{j}=\sum_{k}N_{ij}^{k} \ b_{k}   , \quad N_{ij}^{k}\in\mathbb{N}_{0}\end{equation*} $\mathcal{F}$ is called a *fusion ring/algebra*. In particular, note that $N_{i1}^{j}=N_{1i}^{j}=\delta_{ij}$ (multiplicative identity).

We add the following bit of structure ('*invertibility*'): for every $b_{i}\in\mathcal{B}$, there exists some unique $b_{j}\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $b_{1}$ occurs in the decomposition of $b_{i}\cdot b_{j}$ and $b_{j}\cdot b_{i}$. Denote this 'inverse' by $b_{i^{*}}$. That is, \begin{equation*}\forall i \ \ \exists !  j \ : N_{ij}^{1}=N_{ji}^{1}>0\end{equation*} 
where
\begin{equation*}N_{i^{*}k}^{1}=N_{ki^{*}}^{1}=\delta_{ik}\end{equation*}

**Question**

Referring back to [[1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344079/is-there-an-integral-fusion-ring-which-is-not-of-frobenius-type#comment880109_344079.)], it is asserted (in the comments) that

\begin{equation*}N_{ij}^{k}=N_{j^{*}i^{*}}^{k^{*}}\end{equation*} for all $i,j,k$.

> **Question:** For a fusion algebra with the above structure (neutrality, invertibility and associativity of product), what's the proof (or a reference for one) for this identity?

I've tried a few things but can't quite seem to get it. The result does appear to follow if we can guarantee that $*:i\mapsto i^{*}$ defines an anti-isomorphism of a fusion algebra.

**EDIT:**
After a bit of searching around, it appears that a few places seem to include "$*$" inducing an anti-isomorphism of $\mathcal{F}$ as part of the definition. I suppose that can be motivated by $b_{1}$ being guaranteed to be contained in
\begin{equation*}(b_{i}b_{j})(b_{j^{*}}b_{{i}^{*}}) \quad \text{and} \quad (b_{i}b_{j})(b_{j^{*}}b_{{i}^{*}})\end{equation*}

Still, I wonder if this is absolutely necessary...

Comment: $b_{i}\cdot b_{j}=b_{1}=b_{j}\cdot b_{i}$ is much stronger than what you expected because it implies that $d(b_i)d(b_j)=1$, so that $d(b_i) = d(b_j) = 1$, which means that $\mathcal{B}$ forms a finite groups. Now what you wrote just after is the correct statement.

Comment: All the identities you are talking about reduce to a single one called the *Frobenius reciprocity*:  $$N_{i,j}^k = N_{i^*,k}^j = N_{k,j^*}^i.$$ In particular what you call identity II can be proved directly from the Frobenius reciprocity as follows:  
$$N_{i,j}^k =  N_{i^*,k}^j =  N_{j,k^*}^{i^*}  = N_{j^*,i^*}^{k^*}.$$ 
So you should focus on how to prove the Frobenius reciprocity.

Comment: We can prove that (for a fusion ring) the Frobenius reciprocity is equivalent to $∗$ being an antihomomorphism of algebra, but (you are right) I don't know if it can be proven independently. So, pending a relevant answer to this problem, I have decided to modify the post of me you cited by including the Frobenius reciprocity into the definition of a fusion ring.

Comment: You should completely rewrite your post as follows:  first fix the mistake with "invertibility". Next ask whether "Associativity", "Neutral" and "Inverse/Adjoint" (as written in my post) are sufficient to prove "Frobenius reciprocity" (or if you prefer, that $*$ is an antihomomorphism of algebra).

Comment: What you wrote:
$$\forall i \ \ \exists !  i^{*} \ : N_{i,i^{*}}^{1}=1=N_{i^{*},i}^{1}$$
is also not sufficient. You should write:
$$\forall i \ \ \exists ! j \ : N_{i,j}^{1} > 0,$$
such one is denoted $i^∗$. Next, $N_{i^*,k}^{1} = N_{k,i^*}^{1} = \delta_{i,k}$ (should these last equalities be also in the assumption, or be a renormalization, or be a deduction?).

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Yes, sorry. That was an oopsie on my part, fixed it.

Comment: As I wrote, the usual proof uses the Frobenius reciprocity or (the equivalent) fact that $*$ is an antihomomorphism of algebra. So the question should be: can ‘Frobenius reciprocity’ or ‘$*$ is an antihomomorphism’ be proven independently form each other or should one be assumed?

Comment: The question asks if the identity  can be proved independently of $*$ being an antihomomorphism. I'm now thinking that the antihomomorphism assumption can be motivated by categorifying the fusion ring to a $\mathbb{k}$-linear category (alg. closed field) and using dual hom-spaces to get the identity. Decategorifying, we can choose to include the antihomomorphism (or identity) as part of the structure of a fusion ring with 'invertibility'.

Comment: This identity is precisely a reformulation of ‘∗ is an antihomomorphism’, right? So you are asking whether ‘neutrality’, ‘invertibility’ and ‘associativity’ imply ‘∗ is an antihomomorphism’. A counterexample would be surprising. Using these three axioms you can prove that $b_1$ is ‘contained’ in $(b_ib_j)(b_{j^*}b_{i^*})$:  
$$(b_ib_j)(b_{j^*}b_{i^*})= b_i(b_jb_{j^*})b_{i^*} \ge b_ib_1b_{i^*} =  b_ib_{i^*} \ge b_1$$ It should be close to what expected.

Comment: "This identity is precisely a reformulation of ‘∗ is an antihomomorphism’, right?" Yes. "So you are asking whether ‘neutrality’, ‘invertibility’ and ‘associativity’ imply ‘∗ is an antihomomorphism’." Yes, and I agree a counterexample would be surprising. "Using these three axioms you can prove that $b_{1}$ is..." - yes, this is what I was getting at in the 'Edit' section of the question

Comment: So it answers your edit section, we don't need to assume that $*$ is an antihomomorphism to have $b_1 \le (b_ib_j)(b_{j^*}b_{i^*})$, the three axioms are enough for that. Moreover, it should be close to a proof that $*$ is an antihomomorphism.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Yes, it's not really a proof though - more a motivation for the antihomomorphism to be included as part of the definition.