# Status of the conjectured vanishing of Bloch-Kato H^2

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, motives, galois-cohomology

There is a folklore conjecture that $\operatorname{Ext}^2$ vanishes in the category of **geometric** $p$-adic Galois representations (i.e. representations that are unramified almost everywhere and de Rham at places dividing $p$) over a number field. See for example Conjecture II.3.2.2 of Fontaine--Perin-Riou's *[Autour des conjectures de Bloch et Kato](https://doi.org/10.1090/pspum/055.1)*. This is an avatar in Galois representations of Beilinson's conjecture that the category of mixed motives over a finitely-generated field $k$ has cohomological dimension at most the Kronecker dimension of $k$ (c.f. Remarks 4.12(c) in Uwe Jannsen, *Motivic Sheaves and Filtrations on Chow Groups*, Proceedings of  Symposia in  Pure  Mathematics **55** (1994), Part 1,  pp. 245–302, doi:[10.1090/pspum/055.1](https://doi.org/10.1090/pspum/055.1), [pdf](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/204439781.pdf)).

What is the current state of the art on this conjecture? I was hoping that the experts here could piece together a complete picture of what's currently known.

Part 2 of Theorems A and B of

- Patrick B. Allen, *Deformations of polarized automorphic Galois representations and adjoint Selmer groups*, Duke Math. J. **165**, no. 13 (2016), 2407-2460, doi:[10.1215/00127094-3477342](https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-3477342), arXiv:[1411.7661](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7661),

building on earlier work by Flach and Wiles on modularity lifting, proves specific cases of $\operatorname{Ext}^2$ in the category of $p$-adic Galois representations unramified outside a finite set of places, but with no $p$-adic Hodge theory condition. However, as emphasized to me by David Loeffler, this does NOT prove the corresponding statement in the category of geometric Galois representations.

I would surmise that if there are results in this directions, they would be proven by Galois deformations or Iwasawa theory. In the latter case, I wonder if it might require computationally checking that a certain $p$-adic $L$-value does not vanish in order to prove the conjecture for a specific Galois representation.

Comment: Fontaine--Perrin-Riou is kind of hard to find without a subscription (and my institution doesn't have one), do you know an open-access reference for this conjecture?

Comment: I'll look for one. For now, check your email.

Comment: Allen proves the vanishing of $\mathrm{Ext}^2$ only for a very particular class of representations. Also, although Flach had proved a special case earlier, the application of modularity lifting to this question is due to Wiles, not Flach.

Comment: @naf: You are correct about the attribution. However, as is now clarified in the question, all these results of Flach, Wiles, Allen, etc are answering a different question from the one David is currently asking. I am not aware of any case at all where the "intrinsic" Ext group in the category of geometric Galois reps has been computed.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler: The fact that what was proved by Flach, Wiles, Allen, etc is different from the conjecture of Fontaine and Perrin-Riou was clear in the first version of the question, but the way the question is phrased is still misleading: it seems to suggest that vanishing of $\mathrm{Ext}^2$ is known in full generality in the category of all $p$-adic representations, whereas what is proved is the vanishing of $H^2$  for a very special class of represntations.

Comment: @naf Good point. I tried to make it clearer.

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that $\mathrm{Ext}^2$ does not in fact always vanish in the category of all Galois representations (unramified outside a fixed finite set of places). When $H^2$ should vanish is predicted by a conjecture of Jannsen (Conjecture 1 in "On the l-adic cohomology of varieties over number fields and its Galois cohomology"); he only considers representations arising from smooth projective varieties, but his conjecture can be reformulated to apply to all (pure) geometric Galois representations.